# Value of 'this' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Could someone please explain why 'this' in the following points to the DOM Object and not to Window?

```
$("a").click(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

This yields to:

```
<a id="first" href="http://jquery.com">
```

Consider the following which should be the same scenario:

```
function Foo() {
    this.click = function(f) {
        f();
    }
}

var obj = new Foo();
obj.click(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

What we get here is the Window Object (what I had expected).

Comment: jQuery manipulates `this` where needed.

Comment: As usual, the MDN has some good information about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Comment: I think the person you should ask is John Resig who is responsible for the concept as far as I can tell - I believe it's his doing. Believe it or not - but he is [an active member here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6524/john-resig) as well. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to the context in which the function is executed. jQuery explicitly changes the context of the callback function, whereas your function executes the function in the global context.

to change the context:

```
function Foo() {
    this.click = function(f) {
        f.apply(this);
    }
}
```

or

```
function Foo() {
    this.click = function(f) {
        this.f = f
        this.f();
    }
}
```

For further reading:

http://dailyjs.com/2012/06/18/js101-this/

http://dailyjs.com/2012/06/25/this-binding/

Comment: Good answer man :P `this` also refers to the current element on the DOM that was invoked. +1 rep

Answer (score 7):

In Javascript, OOP is different from what you're accustomed to in languages like Java.

Basically, it is easier to think that there is no OOP and that `this` is just a "hidden argument" of functions.

For example, when you see

```
function f(x, y, z) {
    console.log(this, x, y, z);
}
```

think that in common OOP languages (such as Java) that would be

```
function f(this, x, y, z) {
    console.log(this, x, y, z);
}
```

When you see `var a = b.f(x, y, z);`, think `var a = f(b, x, y, z)`.

When you see `var a = f(x, y, z);` think `var a = f(undefined, x, y, z);` (In browser environment, when [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript) is not activated, it is `f(window, x, y, z);`)

Now it should be easier to understand why `this` in your example means different things in the nested scopes.

Comment: For further details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13441628/334451

Answer (score 4):

`this` will be decided by the context.

If you change your code to below, then `this` will point to `some_other_object`.

```
function Foo() {
    this.click = function(f) {
        f.call(some_other_object);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` is actually defined by the caller, not the context. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13441628/334451 for details.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses the javascript [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function when calling event handlers. From the mdn documentation:

> Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array.