# How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?

Tags: javascript

I've seen [How does "this" keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal), but I don't see that it answers the following.

Given this code:

```
var MyDate = function(date) {
    this.date = date;
};

var obj1 = {
    foo: new Date(),
    bar: new MyDate(this.foo)  //  this.foo is undefined
};

var obj2 = {};
obj2.foo = new Date();
obj2.bar = new MyDate(this.foo);  //  this.foo is undefined

var obj3 = {
    foo: new Date(),
    bar: new MyDate(obj3.foo)
};

var obj4 = {};
obj4.foo = new Date();
obj4.bar = new MyDate(obj4.foo);
```

Why do the first two attempts fail, but the last two work?  If `this` isn't bound to the current object literal, what *is* it bound to?

Comment: you can't use `this` keyword in a javascript object.

Comment: @minitech - yeah, I suspect it's implementation-dependent, but I haven't looked at the spec to confirm.  Maybe it is supposed to work that way.

Comment: #3 works because it's just a regular closure.

Comment: @MarkReed: Nope, it doesn't, I didn't check my page for previously-defined `a`'s :D

Comment: @MarkReed: It's not implementation dependent. It simply doesn't work.

Comment: @x0n: there's no closure there, there's no new function scope.

Comment: @slebetman oh, right ... hmmm.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Javascript is a late binding language. In fact, it is very late binding. Not only is `this` not bound during compile time, it is not even bound during runtime (as most other late binding languages do). In javascript, `this` is bound during call time.

The binding rules are quite different from most other OO languages which is why it seems to confuse a lot of people not familiar with javascript.

Basically, how and where you use `this` in the code does not affect how `this` behaves (it does not matter if it's a standalone function, an object literal etc.) what determines the value of `this` is how you call the function.

The rules are:

**1** - When a function is called as a constructor, a new object is created and `this` is bound to that object. For example:

```
function Foo () {
    this.bar = 1; // when called with the new keyword
                  // this refers to the object just created
}
new Foo().bar;
```

**2** - When called as an object method `this` refers to the object the method belongs to. Basically the name before the last dot. For example:

```
foo.bar = 1;
foo.baz = function () {
    alert(this.bar); // this refers to foo when called as foo.baz()
}
foo.baz();
```

**3** - If used outside of any function or if a function is not called as a method `this` refers to the global object. The javascript spec doesn't give a name to the global object apart from saying that one exists but for browsers it is traditionally called `window`. For example:

```
bar = 1;
alert(this.bar); // this refers to the global object
foo = {
    bar: this.bar // also global object
}
function foofoo () {
    alert(this.bar); // also refers to the global object
}
foofoo();
```

**4** - In an event handler (such as onclick etc.) `this` refers to the DOM element that triggered the event. Or for events not associated with the DOM like `setTimeout` or `XMLHTTPRequest`, `this` refers to the global object. For example:

```
foo.bar = 1;
foo.baz = function () {
    alert(this.bar); // this would normally be foo but if this
                     // function is assigned to an event it would
                     // point to the element that triggered the event
}
somediv.bar = 2;
somediv.onclick = foo.baz; // clicking on somedive alerts 2 instead of 1
```

**5** - Finally, when a function is called using either the `call()` or `apply()` methods `this` can be reassigned to anything whatsoever (google "mdn function.prototype.call"). In this way, any object in javascript can borrow/steal another objects' methods. For example:

```
cat = {
    type: "cat",
    explain: function () {
        return "I am a " + this.type;
    }
}
dog = {
    type: "dog"
}
cat.explain.call(dog); // returns "I am a dog"
```

With `Function.bind()` in modern javascript implementations we now have another rule:

**6** - Functions can also explicitly bind `this` to an object using the `bind()` method. The `bind` method returns a new instance of the function where `this` is bound to the argument passed to `bind`. For example:

```
function explain () {
    return "I am a " + this.type;
}
dog = {
    type: "dog"
}
var dog_explain = explain.bind(dog);
dog_explain(); // returns "I am a dog"
```

ECMAscript 5 introduced strict mode which changes the meaning of this in functions that isn't called as a method or called with call or apply so we have to add a new rule:

**7** - When in strict mode, `this` isn't allowed to refer to the global object (window in browsers). So when a function is not called as a method or `this` isn't bound to anything manually via `call` or `apply` or `bind` then `this` becomes `undefined`:

```
"use strict";
function foo () {
    return this;
}
foo(); // returns undefined instead of the global object
```

ECMAscript 6 introduced arrow functions. Arrow functions change how this behaves by binding early.

**8** - In arrow functions, `this` is bound at the time the function is declared. So `this` in the following code:

```
var x = () => {return this};
```

behaves as if the function is declared like the following code:

```
var x = function () {return this}.bind(this);
```

Note that since the `this` in arrow functions are bound at the time the function is declared **you can't use arrow functions if you want to use inheritance**. That's because the `this` in the function will **always** point to the parent object and will never point to the child object. That means that the only way to make inheritance work with arrow function is to override all arrow functions from the parent object.

Comment: Modified answer, forgot the case for when `this` is used outside of functions.

Comment: `this` refers to `window` in event handlers only in IE browsers. In all other browsers, `this` refers to the target of the event.

Comment: @lanzz: ah forgot. Actually even on IE it normally refers to the target

Comment: In item 5, can you explain where the binding of `this` in `return "I am a " + this.type;` arises from?

Comment: @EdStaub: From the `.call()` method. The first argument to either `call` or `apply` is what you want `this` to be. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Hi !! Thanks for such a great answer ! I just wonder:
`var obj1 = { obj2: { this }}`
Will `this` refer to `obj1` or to `obj2` in this case ?

Comment: @SébastienGarcia-Roméo: That is a syntax error.

Comment: @slebetman thx for answer. It was just pseudo-code for simplicity. Correct line: `var obj1 = { obj2: { fn : function() { var obj_tmp = this; }}}`
What `this` refer to in this case?

Comment: @SébastienGarcia-Roméo: Then the answer is it depends. Read the answer above carefully. In this case it does not matter at all how you write your `this` or how you declare your function. All that matters is how you **call** your function. `asyncFunction(obj1.obj2.fn)` and `this` will be the global object or undefined in strict mode. `asyncFunction(function(){obj1.obj2.fn()})` then `this` will be `obj2`. `asyncFunction(obj1.obj2.fn.bind(mango))` then `this` will be `mango`

Answer (score 15):

I think you may be missing a key difference between functions and object literals:

The body of a function is not evaluated until the function is called.

That means the value of `this` depends on *how* the function is called. If it's called as a method on an object (e.g. `someObj.someFunc()`), then `this` will point to that object within the function body. If it's called as a standalone function (`someFunc()`). them the code in the body will inherit whatever `this` is in the caller's environment. But either way, the value of `this` at the time the function is *defined* doesn't matter at all.

Whereas an object literal is just an expression; if `this` appears, and it's not inside a function body contained within the literal, it's just going to be the value of `this` at the point in the code where that expression appears.

Answer (score 10):

In Javascript, only function calls establish a new `this` context. When you call `foo.bar()`, within the `bar` function, `this` will be bound to `foo`; when you call `foo()`, inside it `this` will be bound to `window`. An object literal constructor is not a method call, so it does not affect `this` in any way; it will still refer to whatever it was referring to outside of the object literal.

Answer (score 8):

`this.foo` is undefined because in all your examples, `this` is referring to the global `window` object. Also, even if you tried `obj1.foo`, it will *still* return undefined because the property hasn't been created until the entire expression is evaluated. Try this instead:

```
var obj1 = {
    foo: new Date(),
    bar: function() {
        return new MyDate( this.foo ); // will work
    }
};
```

It works because by the time you call `obj1.bar()`, the object will have been created by then; and because you're in a function, the `this` object will reference the current object.