# Closure and this clarification?

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering with a little problem  with the context of `this` :

In JavaScript `this` always refers to the "owner" of the function we're executing, or rather,  to the object that a function is a method of.

So, this code :

```
var o={

  f:function ()
     {
       console.log(this); //the owner of the function is `o`
     }
}

console.log(o.f()) // this shows the `o` as this
```

all OK.

So why this code

```
var o = {
    f: function ()
    {
        return function ()
        {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
}
console.log(o.f()())
```

Shows that `this` is the global object/window ?

`o.f()` returns a function  , and then I execute it.but still the Hoster object is `o`.   so why it shows the hoster as `window`?

Comment: The anonymous function you're returning is owned by what/who? No one...meaning `window`. You could always bind `this` to the returned function so that the value of `this` will always refer to `o`. Your last line is technically this: `console.log((function () { console.log(this); })());`

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) you can find some great answers regarding how closures work that might help understand this

Comment: For a more detailed explanation of now `this` works in javascript see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by the object you call the function through, not the place where the function is declared.

For example, if you did the following:

```
var f = o.f;
console.log(f());
```

you'd see that `this` is window as well.

You can also do stuff like this:

```
var o2 = { f: o.f };
console.log(o2.f());
```

There, `this` would be the o2 object, not o.

In your case, o.f is returning a function, which you're invoking without an object reference. In that case, the function invoked is called with `this` set to the global object (which in a browser is `window`).

If you want to preserve the `this` pointer, you'll need to capture it in a closure, like so:

```
var o = {
    f: function ()
    {
        var self = this;
        return function ()
        {
            console.log(self);
        }
    }
}
console.log(o.f()())
```

and then you'd have the right object reference regardless of how it's called.

Answer (score 2):

No. The returned function is just a function, not hosted on any object (which makes `this` default to the global object). Think of that double-invocation as

```
var temp = o.f();
temp();
```

Instead of that "owner context" metapher (which fails too often), better refer to [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). The "owner" object explanation only works for the case when you *call* a method on an object - as soon as you pass the function around (into a callback, `return`ing it, assigning it) it looses its context.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is set by how the function is called, not by where it's stored.

`o.f()` works because you are calling `f()` in the context of `o`.  If you were to copy that function to another object, `this` would change.

For example:

```
var x = {
  a: o.f
};

console.log(x.a()); // logs x, not o.  because the "context" is x
```

In your second example, `o.f()` returns a function, which is then ran with "no context".  That makes the "context" set to `window`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. You are returning a closure and subsequently evaluating it in the scope of the window. If you didn't return the function, you wouldn't have this problem.

The solution:

```
var o = {
  f: function() {
    return function() { console.log(this); }
  }
};
console.log(o.f().apply(o, []));
```

Will transfer ownership of the closure to `o` from nothing (= `window`)

Comment: I know that apply/call/bind can change context/ but that was not my question.

Comment: I have answered your question in the first paragraph: you're returning an unbound closure.

Comment: Instead of passing an empty parameters array to `apply`, you just can pass nothing :-)

Comment: @Bergi: true, though the difference is pretty slim :-)

Answer (score 1):

When a function has no owner, getting the local context falls back to the global context since the real context is `undefined`. And it does the same if the real context is `null`.

All that is true in non strict mode!

In strict mode, getting the local context does not fall back to anything else. The context stays as it is, that is to say in the case of a not owned function : `undefined`. And it's very important to be aware of it.