# How do I store an Object's functions pointers in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, pointers, store

I am trying to store function pointers of an object's functions in an array.But it's giving me problems when I want to access another property of the object within the function.Could any one solve this or give me an idea how to work around it?

```
function O(){
      this.name="hello";
      this.f=function(){
        alert(this.name);//why does "this" refer to the array arr rather than the object?
      };
      this.arr=[];
       this.arr["x"]=this.f;



    }
    var d=new O();
    d.arr["x"]();
```

Comment: See my explanation of how "this" works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, `this` will reference the object that the function was called as a method of (in your case, the array).  You'll want to store a reference to the `O` function somewhere within the scope, such as:

```
function O(){
      var self = this;
      this.name="hello";
      this.f=function(){
        alert(self.name);//why does "this" refer to the array arr rather than the object?
      };
      this.arr=[];
       this.arr["x"]=this.f;



    }
    var d=new O();
    d.arr["x"]();
```

This is a pretty common pattern in JavaScript, and has the added benefit of allowing the function to execute the same way, whether it was called through `d.f()` or `d.arr["X"]()`

Comment: +1 Rather than "attached to" you might say "called as a method of".

Comment: @RobG - Yea good call, I put it in quotes because I couldn't think of a good way to phrase it..