# What do these this`s stand for?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

Here are two widely seen code snippets in JavaScript:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
};

Number.method('integer', function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
});
```

Obviously, the `this` in the second snippet stands for the Number object that's calling the augmented `integer` method. How about the `this` in the first snippet? From the `prototype` property we can guess it stands for the constructor that's being augmented, but the logic behind the snippet is elusive to me. Can anyone detail an explanation? Thanks.

Comment: `this` can mean anything, especially when the function was secretly bound with underscore.js's `bind` and `bindAll`, so the answer is never what it seems. [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) is a high-level reference, however.

Comment: See my answer to this other question for how "this" behaves in javascript. It's not like most other languages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` value inside any function called as a method is always the object the method is being called on. So in `Number.method()`, it will be the `Number` constructor.

It behaves in the exact same way when you call a method on any other object, like:

```
var obj = {
    someMethod : function() { 
        console.log(this);
    }
}
obj.someMethod(); // logs obj
```

The only difference between the above example and yours is that here the method is found on the object itself, while on your example it's found by looking up the prototype chain.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `Number.method()` is just a method call and thus the simplest rule for `this` referencing applies.

Answer (score 2):

[`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is the global object which all *functions* use, just like how [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is the global object for *Numbers*. They can be used as constructors but also apply to literals, i.e. `new Function();` and `function () {}` both relate to `Function`.

The `prototype` *Object* of a constructor is the place where you define properties and methods for all instances made by that constructor. Constructors are *functions* and in *JavaScript*, *functions* are *objects*.

A *method* is just another name for a *function*, usually describing one which is a *property* of an *object*.

Setting a method on `Function.prototype` hence means every *function* inherits that method.

Therefore, the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the method `bar` on `prototype` of constructor `Foo` (`Foo.prototype.bar`) is equal to one of

- `Foo.prototype` if invoked as `Foo.prototype.bar()`
- An *instance* of `Foo` if invoked from that instance, e.g. `z` in `var z = new Foo(); z.bar();`
- Whatever you've defined `this` to be using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
- The global object if invoked without context, i.e. `var b = Foo.prototype.bar; b();`

In your code, `this` is expected to be the second of the above, because `Number` is a *function* because it is a *constructor*, and hence an instance of `Function`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `method` method, `this` will be a reference to the `Function` object that the method is called for. In the example it will be a reference to the `Number` function.

As `Number` is a built in class that you can create using the `new` keyword, it's actually a function, that's why the `Function` prototype applies to it.