# Is this a JavaScript closure bug?

Tags: javascript, closures

Can someone explain me why the code below doesn't print the numbers from 0 to 2 on
`this.closure` unless I do `new crazyClosure(i)` or `crazyClosure.call({}, i)`?

```
var crazyClosure = function (count) {
    var self = this;

    function closure () {
        console.log("closure", count);
    };

    this.closure = function () {
        console.log("this.closure", count);
    };

    console.log("init", count);
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('');
        console.log("call", count);
        closure();
        self.closure();
    }, 0);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    crazyClosure(i);
}
```

Is like if the closure would be attached to `this` instead of to the `crazyClosure` function itself.

I would expect to see:

```
init 0
init 1
init 2
call 0
closure 0
this.closure 0
call 1
closure 1
this.closure 1
call 2
closure 2
this.closure 2
```

but I get

```
init 0
init 1
init 2
call 0
closure 0
this.closure 2
call 1
closure 1
this.closure 2
call 2
closure 2
this.closure 2
```

Adding another example according to answers. In this example I have 2 functions on `this` which is `window` that get overridden every time I call `crazyClosure` though I get the result I was expecting when calling `expected` but I get the result you guys say I should get when calling `unexpected`. According to your explanation I still don't understand how that can happen.

```
function crazyClosure (count) {
    var self = this;

    this.expected = function () {
        console.log("this.expected", count);
        self.unexpected();
    };

    this.unexpected = function () {
        console.log("this.unexpected", count);
    };

    console.log("init", count);
    setTimeout(self.expected, 10);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    crazyClosure(i);
}
```

I get:

```
init 0
init 1
init 2
this.expected 0
this.unexpected 2
this.expected 1
this.unexpected 2
this.expected 2
this.unexpected 2
```

I need to understand this!!! Thanks

Comment: In your code, `this` refers to the global object, which in web browsers is `window`. So what you're doing is creating ONE global called `closure` which is referenced via `this.closure` and you keep replacing THE SAME variable with a new function. Hence, when setTimeout executes it logically executes the last function assigned, three times. If you call the function with `new` instead a new empty object will be created (inheriting from the function's prototype) and assigned to `this`. Either way, this has nothing to do with closures but rather the concept of `this` in javascript.

Comment: See my answer to this other question for a full description of how `this` works in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Comment: To help understand the interpretation of `this` in functions, try reading John Resig's excellent article [Simple “Class” Instantiation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/#postcomment). Unless you are a total genius, you won't understand every word first time - I have read it a dozen times and still need to go back to it on occasions. It provides enormous insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to separate the concept of closure from the concept of Javascript object.

They are totally unrelated and mixing them while learning can bring in more confusion than needed.

In your code the problem is that `crazyClosure` seems like a constructor, but is called as a function so it will not receive a `this` object to work on and thus will work with `this` that is set to `window`.

The result is that `self` is also going to be tied to `window` and the call `self.closure()` will invoke last closure your loop created. All three timeout events will invoke last closure because Javascript will not execute a timeout until your loop terminates.

Please also do yourself a favour and leave immediately the "Javascript closures are broken" attitude. If your **first** thought is that other people's code is broken you are not going to go any far in programming. Please don't take it personally, and don't think it's a rant about how politely you ask a question. The mental habit of thinking that your code is correct and other's people code (a library, the compiler, the OS) is wrong is a true killer... don't fall into that trap.

### Edit

The second example is more convoluted but still the resulting output is what a Javascript implementation should do.

One each call as said before `this` will be `window` because the `new` operator was not used when calling `crazyClosure`.

The two "methods" `expected` and `unexpected` will end up being global functions and you can check this because after the execution you will be able to call `expected()` directly from outside `crazyClosure`.

However while inside `crazyClosure` the value passed to `setTimeout` will be different each time because the global `expected` will have been just overwritten with a new closure that can access the local `count` variable. This `expected` global variable will be overwritten later, but when the value has been already passed to `setTimeout` and the Javascript runtime has stored it away to call it 10 milliseconds later.

All those three closures however in their code call `self.unexpected`, and when this happens this global has been already overwritten three times, so all the three different closures "expected" will call the same closure "unexpected" (the last one) because when the timeout triggers it's what is currently stored in `window.unexpected`.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. Your last sentence should be on SO's [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a question page.

Comment: @nnnnnn: My remark was not about how to ask politely. The mental habit of thinking that your code is correct and bugs are in other people's code (being it a library, the language, the compiler, the OS) is really a big obstacle in progressing, even when you are working alone. It's not about being polite, it's about being able to grow your own programming abilities.

Comment: Yes, I know what you meant, that's why I upvoted. I didn't mention politeness. The "How To Ask" page isn't about asking politely, it's a prompt to try to get people to ask sensible, answerable questions, and to not ask at all unless a thorough search has failed. So what I meant in my previous comment is that it would be nice if your point could be made to everybody thinking of asking a question here _before_ they post "Why is [popular library or language] broken?"

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. At school I learnt that a good title is what it makes people read the article. If you read that title again I'm just asking if its a bug I'm not saying it is.

Comment: @Fede: Sorry if you found this offensive, it wasn't meant to be. The fact that you even wonder if there is a bug in Javascript closures is a problem that will slow you down in the future. This should really be the LAST of your thoughts.

Comment: @6502 can you have a look at my last edit. I've added a similar example that still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @6502 Thanks that kind of makes sense even though I don't find it intuitive at all. I get that the functions get overwritten because they are attached to the same object, its just that in my head I had the idea that the closure gets passed to a function when it gets called, but is like it gets passed when is created. So by overwriting the function you are actually overwriting the closure it will work with too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `new`, `this` at the start of the `crazyClosure` function is the enclosing context, not a new object. So all the calls end calling the closure function on the same `self` (which is `window` if your code isn't embedded).

Each call to

```
this.closure = function () {
    console.log("this.closure", count);
};
```

is equivalent to

```
window.closure = function () {
    console.log("this.closure", count);
};
```

and thus replaces the precedent function. You end up with **only one** `window.closure` function, embedding the last value, and that's this unique function you call three times with `setTimeout`.

Comment: But count is not assigned to this, it belongs to crazyClosure, I would expect to see `closure` and `this.closure` to print the same value.

Comment: You've put a lot of redundant code so it's hard to see what you expected. Can you write what log you expected ?

Comment: Thanks, got that. How that explanation fits with the last example I just added? What am I missing?