# Constructors and Subproperties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web

I have the following:

```
function Vector(X,Y,Direction)
{
    this.X = X,
    this.Y = Y,
    this.Direction = Direction
}

function Particle(Position,Size)
{
    this.Position = Position,
    this.Size = Size,
    this.Velocity = new Vector(0,0,0)
}
```

Vector is a constructor function which creates a vector object, this object is created by another constructor function, Particle, which creates a particle object under the Velocity property.

Will JavaScript parent the constructed Vector object's properties under the Particle object, or under Particle.Velocity? To cut it short, will new Particle() create this:

Particle.X

Or preferably this:

Particle.Velocity.X

This question may be phrased poorly, sorry. I simply have a hard time understanding the scope of the 'this' keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: Particle.X will be undefined.  Particle.Velocity.X will have the value 0.

Comment: You could try that code right on your browser's console...

Comment: @Mike, Thank you! That is exactly what I was asking for!

Comment: @MikeEdwards Actually `particleInstance.Velocity.X`

Comment: @bfavaretto Are you referring to datatype the object represents, or how the object is referenced?

Comment: bfavaretto is correct.  var particleInstance = new Particle(p, s);  particleInstance.Velocity.X === 0; // true

Comment: It would be better if answers were answers not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be `Particle.Velocity.X`. Not specifically because of the scope of `this` but because you did this:

```
this.Velocity = new Vector(0,0,0);
```

You're assigning to the `Velocity` property of the `Particle` object.

But `this` works differently in javascript so it's worth spending some time understanding it. It's not bound directly to the object where it's declared/written but rather bound at run time to different things depending on how the function/method is called.

For example, consider the following:

```
var foo = {};
foo.name = 'Frank';
foo.say = function () {alert('My name is' + this.name)}
foo.say();
```

as you would expect, the code above alerts "My name is Frank". But, if you do this:

```
var bar = {};
bar.name = 'Benny';
bar.say = foo.say;
bar.say();
```

the code above will alert "My name is Benny". That's because `this` is bound to the last word/name before the dot. So even if the function was originally declared in the context of `foo`, once it's called with `bar` as it's container object the `this` inside it will refer to `bar`.

For a complete description of how `this` works in javascript see my answer to this other question: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

Comment: Great to know that JavaScript isn't too illogical.