# When you pass 'this' as an argument?

Tags: javascript, this, bind

I'm trying to learn about `this`, and it's confusing me a bit here:

```
var randomFunction = function(callback) {
    var data = 10;
    callback(data);
};

var obj = {
    initialData:  20,
    sumData: function(data) {
        var sum = this.initialData + data;
        console.log(sum);
    },
    prepareRandomFunction: function() {
        randomFunction(this.sumData.bind(this));
    }
};

obj.prepareRandomFunction();
```

Is `this` designed to set itself where it is first rendered in code?

For instance, in my example I'm successfully using it to refer to `obj` and also binding the function to `obj`, but since `this` is being passed as a callback function, what is stopping it from being set as `randomFunction` (i.e. what's stopping it from literally passing "this.sumData.bind(this)" so that `this` is set to `randomFunction` when it gets called from there)?

#### Updated

I'm not exactly asking how this works generally (I don't think). I'm mainly curious to know why `this` gets set where I define it as the argument of my `randomFunction` call, and not where `callback` gets called within `randomFunction`.

I could be wrong, but if I were to swap `this.sumData.bind(this)` with the `callback(data)` that I currently have I think I would get a different result. Is that because `callback` is a reference to `this.sumData.bind(this)` when it was first defined (and where `this` is `obj`)?

---

I think I've learned through this scenario that `this` is set when it's executed. It's not passed as a argument to be set later when the argument is called down the line.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://perfectionkills.com/know-thy-reference/

Comment: `this` is set here `obj.prepareRandomFunction()`. The caller decides what `this` is, unless you use `bind`.

Comment: See MDN reference on this keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this   .

Comment: @elclanrs so, does passing it as an argument mean that it is being called? Because it is actually being called for run in randomFunction. I mean, it's working, so I guess the answer is yes...

Comment: `this` doesn't get set to a function. it points to the function context, in other words, the object that own that function (called a method). So `this` isn't what is passed as a callback to randomFunction().

Answer (score 30):

`this` inside a function call gets set according to how a function is called.  There are six main ways that `this` gets set.

1. **Normal Function Call:**  In a normal function call such as `foo()`, `this` is set to either the global object (which is `window` in a browser or `global` in nodejs) or to `undefined` (in JavaScript's strict mode).
2. **Method Call:**  If a method is called such as `obj.foo()` where the method `foo` is a normal method declaration using the `function` keyword or using the regular method declaration syntax for a `class`, then `this` is set to `obj` inside the function.
3. **.apply() or .call():**  If `.apply()` or `.call()` is used, then `this` is set according to what is passed to `.apply()` or `.call()`.  For example, you could do `foo.call(myObj)` and cause `this` to be set to `myObj` inside of `foo()` for that particular function call.
4. **Using new:**  If you call a function with `new` such as `new foo()`, then a new object is created and the constructor function `foo` is called with `this` set to the newly created object.
5. **Using .bind():**  When using `.bind()` a new stub function is returned from that call that internally uses `.apply()` to set the `this` pointer as was passed to `.bind()`.  FYI, this isn't really a different case because `.bind()` can be implemented with `.apply()`.
6. **Using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) Fat Arrow Function** Defining a function via the arrow syntax in ES6+ will bind the current lexical value of `this` to it.  So, no matter how the function is called elsewhere (with any of the previous ways to call it), the `this` value will be set by the interpreter to the value that `this` has when the function was defined.  This is completely different than all other function calls.

There's sort of a seventh method, via a **callback function**, but it isn't really its own scheme, but rather the function calling the callback uses one of the above schemes and that determines what the value of `this` will be when the callback is called.  You have to consult either the documentation or the code for the calling function or test it yourself to determine what `this` will be set to in a callback.

---

**What is important to understand in JavaScript is that every single function or method call in JavaScript sets a new value for `this`.  And, which value is set is determined by how the function is called.**

So, if you pass a method as a plain callback, that method will not, by default, get called as `obj.method()` and thus will not have the right value of `this` set for it.  You can use `.bind()` to work around that issue.

It's also useful to know that some callback functions (such as DOM event handlers) are called with a specific value of `this` as set by the infrastructure that calls the callback function.  Internally, they all use `.call()` or `.apply()` so this isn't a new rule, but is something to be aware of.  The "contract" for a callback function may include how it sets the value of `this`.  If it does not explicitly set the value of `this`, then it will be set according to rule #1.

In ES6, calling a function via an arrow function, maintains the current lexical value of `this`.  Here's an example of the array function maintaining the lexical `this` [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this):

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

---

Your example of `obj.prepareRandomFunction();` is rule #2 above so `this` will be set to `obj`.

Your example of `randomFunction(this.sumData.bind(this))` is rule #1 above so `this` inside of `randomFunction` will be set to the global object or `undefined` (if in strict mode).

Since randomFunction is calling a callback function which itself used `.bind()`, then the value of `this` inside the callback function when it is called will be set to the value of `this` that was passed to `.bind()` in `this.sumData.bind(this)` as via rule #5 above.  `.bind()` actually creates a new function who's job it is to call the original function AFTER setting a custom value of `this`.

---

Here are a couple other references on the topic:

*[How to avoid "this" refering to the DOM element, and refer to the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623738/how-to-avoid-this-refering-to-the-dom-element-and-refer-to-the-object/19623763#19623763)*

[A better understanding of this](http://perfectionkills.com/know-thy-reference/)

*[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/26574449#26574449)*

---

Note, that with the use of `.apply()` or `.call()` or `.bind()`, you can create all sorts of somewhat odd things and sometimes quite useful things that could never be done in something like [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B). You can take any function or method in the world and call it as if it were a method of some other object.

For example, this is often used to make a copy of the items in the `arguments` object into an array:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

or similarly:

```
var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

This takes the array's `.slice()` method and calls it, but supplies it with an arguments object as the `this` pointer.  The `arguments` object (though not an actual array), has just enough array-like functionality that the `.slice()` method can operate on it and it ends up making a copy of the `arguments` items into an actual array which can then be operated on directly with real array operations.  This type of chicanery can't be done willy-nilly.  If the array `.slice()` method relied on other array methods that are not present on the `arguments` object, then this trick would not work, but since it only relies on `[]` and `.length`, both of which the `arguments` object has, it does actually work.

So, this trick can be used to "borrow" methods from any object and apply them to another object as long as the object you are applying them to supports whatever methods or properties that the method actually uses.  This can't be done in C++ because methods and properties are "hard bound" at compile time (even virtual methods in C++ are bound to a specific v-table location established at compile time), but can be easily done in JavaScript because properties and methods are looked up live at runtime via their actual name so any object that contains the right properties and methods will work with any method that operates on those.

Comment: Added some more references and notes about some cool uses of `.apply()` and `.call()`.

Comment: Great job. I feel like a fool who always used 'this' because of option 2, but I guess that came with Python programming.

Answer (score 4):

Step by step.

1. `this` inside `prepareRandomFunction` is `obj`

   ```
    obj.prepareRandomFunction()
   ```
2. `randomFunction` takes a function:

   ```
    randomFunction(this.sumData);
   ```
3. That function gets called:

   ```
    callback(data);
   ```

   Notice `callback` is called without a dot, which means it has no value for `this`, which means `this` is the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode).
4. `sumData` gets called:

   ```
    var sum = this.initialData + data;
   ```

   `this` is the global object, `initialData` doesn't exist, you add `undefined` to `data`. Unexpected results.

   **Solution:** bind `this` permanently:

   ```
    randomFunction(this.sumData.bind(this));
   ```
5. `sumData` runs, `this` is `obj`, `obj.initialData` is `20`. It works.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this designed to set itself where it is first rendered in code?

No. It's set by how a function is called or by using *bind*.

> For instance, in my example I'm successfully using it to refer to obj

Because the function is called using:

```
obj.prepareRandomFunction();
```

which sets *this* in the function to *obj*.

> and also binding the function to obj

in:

```
var obj = {
  ...
  prepareRandomFunction: function() {
      randomFunction(this.sumData.bind(this));
  }
};
```

since *prepareRandomFunction* has been called with *obj* as *this*, then the value of *this* within *obj.sumData* is set to *obj*, and the call to *randomFunction* effectively resolves to:

```
  randomFunction(obj.sumData.bind(obj));
```

> but since this is being passed as a callback function, what is stopping it from being set as randomFunction

The fact that you've set *this* to *obj* in the call. If you want *this* to be *randomFunction*, you'll need to set it to that. *randomFunction* has no intrinsic value for *this*, it is set by how the function is called (or use of *bind*).

> (i.e. what's stopping it from literally passing "this.sumData.bind(this)" so that this is set to randomFunction)?

Because *this* isn't *randomFunction* when that code is executed.

So:

```
obj.prepareRandomFunction();
```

calls *prepareRandomFunction* with *this* set to *obj*, which then does (replacing *this* with *obj*:

```
randomFunction(obj.sumData.bind(obj));
```

Within *randomFunction*, *this* hasn't been set so it defaults to the global object (irrelevant really as it's not used here). Then:

```
var randomFunction = function(callback) {
    var data = 10;
    callback(data);
};
```

Which creates a local variable *data* with a value of 10, then calls *sumData* with its *this* set to *obj* and passes the value of *data*. Then:

```
sumData: function(data) {
    var sum = this.initialData + data;
    console.log(sum);
},
```

and since *this* is *obj*, the assignment effectively resolves to:

```
  var sum = obj.initialData + 10;
```

which is 30.

Comment: Thanks. "Because 'this' isn't randomFunction when that code is executed." Is what I was really looking for.

I.e. 'this' is not passed as an argument to be determined later. It's always set when 'this' is executed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for such a long answer but I didn't have time to write a shorter one. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

This is a self-reference of an object. When you create an object, either by using the new operator, declaring it as an object literal or by calling one of the builtin functions of JavaScript, this is going to be assigned to it.

But as the scoping of JavaScript is dynamic and rather non - transient, you usually cannot rely too much on the this object. This is why you often see constructs such as *oThis*: this or var o