# This selector in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this, selector

I was wondering how to use the $(this) selector in a function. I have tried multiple ways found on the internet but none seem to work.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do

```js
function bobsCar() {
   $(this).toggle();
}

$('p').click(function() {
   bobsCar();
});
```

Comment: What element do you want t use the function for ????

Comment: For the rules on how `this` is set in a function, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676.  Since `bobsCar()` is a normal function call, per the Javascript rules, `this` will be either `window` or `undefined` (if running in strict mode).  The value of `this` is NOT automatically preserved when you call a function.  It is reset according to how the function is called (see the above referenced rules).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to execute the function with a custom context like.

```
function bobsCar() {
   $(this).toggle();
}

$('p').click(function() {
   bobsCar.call(this);
});
```

In your case since you are calling `bobsCar` without a context, `this` inside it refers to the `window` object that is why it is not working.

- [Function.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function bobsCar() {
   $(this).toggle();
}

jQuery('p').click(function() {
   bobsCar.call(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>click me</p>
```

You need to understand JavaScript contexts. By default if you call a method inside your click callback, it will use the global context (in this case `window` - try console logging `this` in your broken function), not the one in the callback. You can use `call` or `apply` to specify the context (in this case `this` refers to the DOMNode element in the callback, so we pass the same context to the function and it works).

This is a good article on the topic: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-JavaScript-function-invocation-and-this/

Comment: Hmm... Interesting i never used `fn.call(args)` but this seems interesting.

Comment: First time seeing calling function like this. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` inside the click event handler is not a string representation of a selector. It is a DOM node.

If you want to override the normal value of `this` for a function, you can specify it with `call` or `apply`.

```
bobsCar.call(this);
```

You could pass it as an argument instead.

```
bobsCar(this);

function bobsCar(domNode) {
    $(domNode).toggle();
}
```

You should probably just use the function as the event handler in the first place though.

```
$('p').click(bobsCar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use `this` in called function. You must have to pass selected object as function argument.

```
function bobsCar(element) {
   $(element).toggle();
}

$('p').click(function() {
   bobsCar(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This inside the function no longer reefers tot he 'p' tag, you could pass it

```
function bobsCar(el) {
  el.toggle();
}

$('p').click(function() {
   bobsCar($(this));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript the $(this) is a context-pointer. It gives you the top-most context that is placed on the stack.

> function bobsCar(elm) { console.log(elm);
>   $(elm).parent().toggleClass(); }
>
> $('p').click(function() { var $this=$(this);    bobsCar($this); });

jsfiddle.net/q325d6zw