# How come IIFE's this variable refers to the global scope?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        }());
    }
};
```

This outputs:

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar
outer func:  self.foo = bar
inner func:  this.foo = undefined
inner func:  self.foo = bar
```

I understand this occurs because the IIFE's `this` refers to the global scope, not `myObject`. But why does it refer to the global scope? How come IIFE's `this` variable refers to the global scope?

Comment: Douglas Crockford's Javascript: The Good Parts was a huge help to me in understanding JS's function scope quirks. http://it-ebooks.info/book/274/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this has a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how JS functions work. If you don't implicitly (via `object.method()` syntax) or explicitly (via `.call`, `.apply` or `.bind`) set the value of `this`, it defaults to the global object, unless you're in strict mode.

So if you took an IIFE, and used `.call`, passing it a different object, you'd get that object as the `this` value.

```
    (function() {
        console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo); // "bar"
        console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
    }).call({foo: "bar"});
```

Answer (score 2):

Any function call in Javascript resets the value of `this` according to how the function was called.  An IIFE is such a function call.

So, if you don't call that function in any special way, the value of `this` will be set to `window` in regular mode in a browser or `undefined` in strict mode.  That is how Javascript handles `this` when making a normal function call.

As a surprise to many, there is no concept of "preserving" the current value of `this` when you call a function in Javascript.  You would have to call it a specific way to set the value of `this` if you want to control it.

In your code, you could preserve the value of `this` by using `.call()` with the IIFE like this:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        }).call(this);
    }
};
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/66cL4zt5/

See [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for a summary of all the ways that `this` is set.

Comment: Added jsFiddle that demonstrates using `.call(this)`.