# Putting function in Array messes its parent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a class in node that runs a set of stages that can be easily added or removed. My current code looks like this:

```
function MyClass(){
    this._stages = [this.function1, this.function2];
    this._info = {'a':'special object info'};
};
MyClass.prototype.run = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i<this._stages.length; i++){
        this._stages[i]();
    }
};
MyClass.prototype.function1 = function(){
    this.subfunction1();
};
MyClass.prototype.subfunction1 = function(){};
```

Unfortunately, it seems like putting the function inside the `Array` messes up their 'parent', and I get an error saying that

```
TypeError: Object function (query) {
[...long list of elements]
} has no method 'subfunction1'
    at Array.MyClass.function1...
```

Is there a way to accomplish this by-stage execution without having this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put it in the array, it loses its association with `this`.  So, when you then call those functions, they won't have the right `this` value.  You can fix it with `.bind()`:

```
function MyClass(){
    this._stages = [this.function1.bind(this), this.function2.bind(this)];
    this._info = {'a':'special object info'};
};
```

---

A different way to fix it would be to reattach `this` when you call the functions by using `.call()` to specifically set the `this` pointer like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.run = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i<this._stages.length; i++){
        this._stages[i].call(this);
    }
};
```

---

As an explanation, when you do this:

```
var x = this.function1;
x();
```

then, all that's in the `x` variable is a pointer to the `function1` function.  If you call `x()`, it will be called without any object reference so `this` in the function will be either the global object or `undefined` if running in strict mode.  It will not be the desired object.

`.bind()` creates a stub function that stores the `this` value and then calls the original function with the right object reference such that the `this` value is set properly.

If you want a review of how `this` is set, you can see this answer: [When you pass 'this' as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676)