# Double issue with "this" scope in xmlhttprequest javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, callback, xmlhttprequest

I have two huge issues with `this` scope in my javascript code. 
After creating `setAJAXGet` object, callback function was lost and couldn't be called correctly. So instead of calling `this.funct` I set `ajax.parent = this`; and call `this.parent.funct` - works ok.

```
function setAJAXGet() {
    this.askServer = function() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.parent = this; 
    ajax.contentType = "charset:utf-8";
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {
            this.parent.funct(ajax.responseText);
            }
    }
    ajax.open( "GET", this.url+'?'+this.vars, true );
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    if (navigator.onLine) ajax.send( null ); else this.functError();
    }
this.functError;
this.funct;
this.vars;
this.url;
}
```

Things get a little more complicated when I try to call `setAJAXGet()` from the other object and the callback function is inside that object. Callback function is called correctly, but every other function in the object (from the callback function) gets invisible.

```
function someObject() {
    this.asyncGet = function() {
    var get = new setAJAXGet();
    //do some config here...
    get.funct = this.processAsyncData;
    get.askServer();
    }

    this.someOtherFunction = function() {
    }

    this.processAsyncData = function(ajaxText) {
    // ajaxText is OK
    this.someOtherFunction();
    // this.someOtherFunction is not defined (how so?)
    }

this.asyncGet();
}
```

I can solve this problem by passing object to the `processAsyncData` by modified `setAJAXGet()` as argument, but it looks ugly.

```
function someObject() {
    this.asyncGet = function() {
    var get = new modifiedSetAJAXGet();
    //do config here...
    get.object = this; // stores 'this' and sends it to callback as argument
    get.funct = this.processAsyncData;
    get.askServer();
    }

    this.someOtherFunction = function() {
    }

    this.processAsyncData = function(object, ajaxText) {
    // ajaxText is OK
    object.someOtherFunction();
    // object.someOtherFunction works just fine
    }

this.asyncGet();
}
```

I believe that you know more elegant solution.

Comment: I'd suggest you read this primer on how the value of `this` is set: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676

Comment: Why not the classic `var self = this` at the top of your function?

Comment: @Mathletics where should I put `var self = this`?

Comment: @jfriend00: Thank you, this is very nice summary, but how should I fix my code?

Comment: @JanŁukaszGórski as the first line inside `someObject` function definition.

Comment: @Mathletics: Thank you, `self` instead of `object` passing works fine. But how can I modify the code to use `this` inside callback function without passing the object?

Comment: @Mathletics, @jfriend00 I changed `this.parent.funct(ajax.responseText);` to `this.parent.funct.call(this.parent.object, ajax.responseText);` when `this.parent.object` is calling object and it works with `this`. I find JavaScript confusing at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to follow the objective of your code, but the main thing you need to learn in Javascript is that the value of `this` within a function is controlled by how the function is called.  This is confusing in Javascript until you fully grok that all that matters is how the function is called.  It doesn't matter how things are declared, only how they are called.

When you do something like this:

```
get.funct = this.processAsyncData;
```

What gets put into `get.funct` is a pointer to the `processAsyncData` method.  There is no connection at all to the `this` value in `get.funct` any more.  So, when sometime later you call `get.funct()`, it will not be the same as calling `this. processAsyncData()`.  The value of `this` will be lost.

This is where `.bind()` comes in handy.  You can read about .bind [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).  What it does is to create a temporary function stub that reattaches your value of `this` so that the above separation does not happen.  So, you could use it like this:

```
get.funct = this.processAsyncData.bind(this);
```

Then, when you call `get.funct()`, it will generate exactly the same function call and value of `this` as `this.processAsyncData()` would because the `.bind()` has created a function stub to automatically reattach the desired value of `this`.

As I posted in an earlier comment, there's a very good summary of how the value of `this` is controlled in this other answer: [When you pass 'this' as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676).

Note, my proposed solution is different than what you mentioned in your comment.  I'm suggesting that you fix the problem earlier in the process so then the `.funct` method can be called by anyone at any time without having to do something special.