# Why is this function logging undefined (JavaScript closure)

Tags: javascript, closures

Wondering why the init function ends up logging undefined since startDate is defined before logStartDate is called.

 The Code:

```
var startDate;

var init = function(startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
    logStartDate();
};

var logStartDate = function() {
    console.log(startDate);
};

init('2015-01-02');
```

Comment: Maybe `window.startDate` instead of `this.startDate`? But I would suggests just using different names for the variables, like the answers below.

Comment: Why are you using `this.startDate`  inside a regular function?  That would be an error if you were running in strict mode because this is a poor construction.  Start there to fix your problem.

Comment: Why is it a poor construction, whats a better construction?

Comment: Also, where do you think you have created a closure?

Comment: Isnt a function expression a closure?

Comment: @DanielKobe Nope. A closure is when a function "closes over" another variable in a parent scope. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for more details.

Comment: I've added an answer which explains the questions you asked me in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that your code does not work because the value of `this` is not what you expect it to be so thus `this.startDate` does not change the variable `startDate` you have in your code and thus that variable was never initialized.

You are misusing `this` in that reference so that is the place to start in fixing your code.  In fact, if you ran your code in `strict` mode, your code would generate an error because `this` would be `undefined`.  `strict` mode is designed explicitly to prevent poor coding practices such as accidentally using `this` the wrong way.

> Why is `this.startDate` a poor construction, what's a better construction?

`this` is used to refer to an object inside a method call as in `obj.method()`.  Inside of `method`, `this` will refer to `obj` or `this` can be used in a few other circumstances when the caller of a function explicitly causes the value of `this` to be set to a meaningful value.  In a normal function call, `this` will either be the global object or in strict mode will be `undefined` and should generally not be used.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016676/816620) for a listing of exactly what situations the value of `this` is set to something unique.

Inside a normal function call where `this` is not explicitly set for you by the caller, you should not be using `this` at all.  In fact, if you run your code in strict mode (which is highly recommended), the value of `this` will be `undefined` in your `init` function.

If you're just trying to set the higher level scoped variable named `startDate` to the value of whatever was passed to `init`, then you should change your argument name to the `init` function to a non-conflicting name and then just refer directly to the `startDate` variable like this:

```
var startDate;

var init = function(initialDate) {
    startDate = initialDate;
    logStartDate();
};

var logStartDate = function() {
    console.log(startDate);
};

init('2015-01-02');
```

> Isn't a function expression a closure?

A closure is only created under certain circumstances when some sort of internal reference inside a function is lasting which keeps the scope of the function alive after it finishes executing.  All function expressions are not closures.  You do not have a closure in this code.  See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for much more discussion of closures.

Answer (score 0):

Because inside `init` you're setting the value of `this.Startdate` (a private member var of `init`).

You need to modify to use `window` scope:

```
var startDate;

var init = function(date) {
    startDate = date;
    logStartDate();
};

var logStartDate = function() {
    console.log(startDate);
};

init('2015-01-02');
```

Comment: True but in why does his code not work in non-strict mode? Shouldn't `var startDate` generate a member on `window`? Then the function is called with the `window` context so shouldn't this technically work?

Comment: Because Im using Node.js

Comment: @DanielKobe Then replace `window` with the general global object. The point is, if you're placing a variable in the global scope, call a function using the global scope, then you should be able to access it's properties (i.e. any declared variables) using `this`. That being said, I wouldn't suggest writing code like that but it's an interesting problem.

Comment: I should point out that this code works as OP expects if run in Chrome Dev Tools but fails when run in the browser. [fiddle showing example](http://jsfiddle.net/h3moq1rh/)

Answer (score 0):

Because *startDate*`2` equals to *startDate*`1`, not to other *startDate*.

```js
var startDate;   // 1

var init = function(startDate) {  // startDate here is '2015-01-02'
  this.startDate = startDate;     // not equal to startDate line 1
  logStartDate();
};

var logStartDate = function() {
  console.log(startDate);         // 2, equal to startDate line 1
};

init('2015-01-02');
```

use this one instead:

```js
var startDate;

var init = function(date) {
  startDate = date;
  logStartDate();
};

var logStartDate = function() {
  console.log(startDate);
};

init('2015-01-02');
```

Comment: How can I set  startDate 1 to the init parameter?

Comment: @DanielKobe Just use another name for param, like `date`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that logStartDate is trying to console.log the first startDate variable you defined but did not assign a value to, hence it is returning as 'undefined'. The poor choice of variable name has also contributed partly to this confusion.

```
var startDate;                //you defined a new variable startDate
var init = function(date) {   //you defined init, and passed a parameter called date (renamed for clarity)
    this.startDate = date;    //you set this.startDate to the date parameter
    logStartDate();           //you call logStartDate() but have not passed this.startDate as an argument, 
};
var logStartDate = function() {
    console.log(startDate);     // you are console logging the original startDate variable defined at the top of the code block, which did not get assigned a value
};
init('2015-01-02');
```

A better implementation would be something like this

```
var init = function(date) {
    logStartDate(date);
};

var logStartDate = function(date) {
    console.log(date);
};

init('2015-01-02');
```

Comment: There is no point creating a global variable startDate when all you need the init function to do is to console.log whatever string you have as the argument when invoking it.