# Why didn’t the anonymous function pick up the containing scope’s this object?

Tags: javascript

I saw the code below in a text book on closures:

```
var name = "The Window";

var object = {
  name: "My Object",
  getNameFunc: function () {
    return function () {
      return this.name;
    };
  }
};

alert(object.getNameFunc()()); // "The Window"
```

A detailed explanation on why the this object in the inner function cannot access the object scope but rather accesses the global scope could be of great help.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, I fixed those in the edit.

Comment: Essentially, in javascript EVERYTHING is an object, even a function.  So when you create an anonymous function, it is an object and thus has a this pointer for it.  The standard way of dealing with this is to declare a variable before the function like var self = this, then use that instead.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound demanding but need your guys@andy@michael

Comment: EVERY function call in Javascript sets a new value of `this` based on how the function was called.  The value of `this` is never automatically preserved from one function call to the next.  See [How `this` gets set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for the 5 ways that  the value of `this` gets controlled.

Comment: That is the how but I wanna know why the this object changes in an anonymous function.what brings this about?@nurdyguy @jfriend00

Comment: Because EVERY single function call in Javascript sets a new value of `this`.  If there is no specific way that `this` is purposefully set (e.g. one of the 5 ways listed in my previously linked answer), then `this` is set to `window` or `undefined` (if in strict mode) and that's what you're seeing.  The last function call in `object.getNameFunc()()` is just a normal function call which causes `this` to be set back to the global object.  It is how Javascript works.  In your case, you can either use `.bind()` or you can use `var self = this;` in the parent function and then refer to `self`.

Comment: I added an answer that covers what I've said in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, every single function call causes a new value of `this` to be set and if it is just a plain function call, then `this` is set to either the global object (which is `window` in a browser) or `undefined` (if running in strict mode).  That's what is happening for you.  In this line:

```
object.getNameFunc()()
```

`object.getNameFunc()` makes the first method call and returns the internal anonymous function.  Then, the last `()` is just a regular function call of that function and that regular function call causes `this` to get set to the global object (`window` in your case).  Any plain function call resets the value of `this` to `window` or `undefined`.  This is how Javascript works.

Here's a simple demo that show you how `this` is reset:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for the five ways that the value of `this` is controlled.

You can work around this issue in several ways by either saving the value of `this` in the parent function or using one of the methods to explicitly control the value of `this`.

One of the simpler mechanisms to understand is to just save the value you want in the parent function:

```js
var myName = "The Window";
    
var object = {
  myName: "My Object",
  getNameFunc: function () {
    var self = this;
    return function () {
      return self.myName;
    };
  }
};

document.write(object.getNameFunc()()); // "My Object"
```

Or, you can use `.bind()`:

```js
var myName = "The Window";

var object = {
  myName: "My Object",
  getNameFunc: function () {
    return function () {
      return this.myName;
    }.bind(this);
  }
};

document.write(object.getNameFunc()()); // "My Object"
```

FYI, I changed your variable name to `myName` so there could never be any confusion in following what was happening with `window.name` which already exists in the browser environment.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into separate function invocations. Instead of

```
 object.getNameFunc()()
```

let's break that down, call the first function, then invoke the result of that.

```
 var theFunc = object.getNameFunc(); // invocation 1
 theFunc();   // invocation 2
```

in invocation 1 we call getNameFunc(), and we specify a context (we have something before the . ) So within that invocation "this" has a specified value, **object**

In the second case we are calling the function "bare", no specified context, so we have the global context.

Answer (score 0):

In `getNameFunc()`, `this` refers to `object`. It returns a function which is **not** bound to a context, just to the containing scope. The context (what `this` refers to) is **not** inherited (although scopes are).

Inner functions do **not** inhert the context which they are defined in, although they do inherit the scope they are defined in.

One way to work around this is to `.bind()` the returned function to the context:

```
getNameFunc: function () {
  return function () {
    return this.name;
  }.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Don't get you .... Are you saying that variable object or lexical context are not inherited?