# javascript output example from code

Tags: javascript

im new to javascript and would like to know what will be the output of the code:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
    console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
    (function() {
        console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
    }());
    }
};
```

Not sure how foo works yet.

Comment: Maybe you could try this by yourself? You don't need a community to try that code, you can do it by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every function call in Javascript resets the value of `this` based on how the function was called (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for the five ways that `this` is controlled).

So, when you use the IIFE structure `(function() { ... })()` which is just a normal function call, the value of `this` is reset to either the `window` object or to `undefined` if running in strict mode.

So, if you are not running in `strict` mode, then the `this.foo` reference in the inner func will be attempting to access `window.foo` which will probably be `undefined`.

And, sure enough when I run this in [a jsFiddle that is not in strict mode](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/v06de7sj/), and actually call `myObject.func()` the console shows:

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar
outer func:  self.foo = bar
inner func:  this.foo = undefined
inner func:  self.foo = bar
```

An additional `console.log()` statement confirms that in the inner func `this === window` and, of course, `window.foo` is `undefined`.

---

If you [run your code in strict mode](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8fqf4nm6/), then calling `myObject.func()` will generate this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined` because in the inner func, `this === undefined`.