# Chain-Linking Returned Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

I am developing a Javascript framework that makes working with the DOM easier. Right now I have an object called `ez` that has methods for working with the DOM. Here is my code:

```
var ez = new Object();
ez.get = function(v,type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'id': this.elementData = document.getElementById(v);
            break;
        case 'class': this.elementData = document.getElementsByClassName(v);
            break;
        case 'tag': this.elementData = document.getElementsByTagName(v);
            break;
        case 'css': this.elementData = document.querySelectorAll(v);
    }
    return this; //returns itself
}
ez.content = function() {
        alert(this.elementData); //returns undefined
}
```

Then, in another Javascript file (which comes after this one in the HTML file) I execute the following code onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    ez.get('test','id').content(); //"test" is the id of an element in the DOM and it does have a text node called "test" also
}
```

What I want is for `ez.get()` to return *itself* (which it does seem to do) and then for it to **retain its** `elementData` **property**. The issue is that the property's value is not retained after I return *this*, and it becomes `undefined`. I'm trying to do something similar to what JQuery does, where you can chain-link method calls because each method returns the object.

**UPDATE**

Okay, I did shorten my code for the post but here is the full code:

```
var ez = new Object();
ez.get = function(v,type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'id': this.elementData = document.getElementById(v);
            break;
        case 'class': this.elementData = document.getElementsByClassName(v);
            break;
        case 'tag': this.elementData = document.getElementsByTagName(v);
            break;
        case 'css': this.elementData = document.querySelectorAll(v);
    }
    return this;
}
ez.isElementSet = function(execute) {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty('elementData')) {
        return execute();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
ez.content = function() {
    return this.isElementSet(function() {
        return this.elementData.innerHTML;
    });
}
window.onload = function() {
    alert(ez.get('test','id').content());
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>EzDom</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='ez.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='test'>Test.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/t61669cL/

Comment: Hmm. What I did to fix it was changed all instances of "this" to "ez" and then it worked.

Comment: It works fine with `this` in my jsFiddle so obviously you are doing something different than just the code you posted in your question.

Comment: I updated this with my full code now. It does not work for me unless I change "this" to "ez" and I'm not sure why. Here's a new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t61669cL/2/

Comment: I posted a bad link before, this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t61669cL/2/ and if you change every "this" to "ez" you'll see it works then.

Comment: I have another interesting this. The only "this" you need to change to "ez" is the one in the "content()" method call. Here is a fixed version https://jsfiddle.net/t61669cL/3/ and you can compare it to the broken one  jsfiddle.net/t61669cL/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this function:

```
ez.isElementSet = function(execute) {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty('elementData')) {
        return execute();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When you call `execute()`, the value of `this` gets reset (as it does on every function call) and will no longer be the value you want.  That's why you have to use `ez.elementData.innerHTML` inside that callback.  If you expect the value of `this` to be something specific in a callback function, then you have to specifically make sure the code sets it that way.  There are a couple options here.  The simplest is probably to use `.bind()` when setting the callback.

```
ez.content = function() {
    return this.isElementSet(function() {
        return this.elementData.innerHTML;
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ejneaa1x/

For further info on how `this` is set when a function is called see: [When you pass 'this' as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676)

Comment: So what bind() does is basically attatches "this" to that function?

Comment: Pretty much.  `.bind()` returns a new function that calls the original with a specific value of `this`.