# How does Javascript evaluate "this"?

Tags: javascript, variables, object, methods

I am trying to understand some basic javascript .

I have the following snippet. We have the `name` variable which in both cases are referenced over getName Method.

First alert outputs `HocusPocus`, while the second one outputs `GeorgeThomas`. But I do not understand how `this` refers to name in this case

```js
    var name = 'Gerorge Thomas';
    var obj = {
       name: 'Cinderella',
       value: {
          name: 'HocusPocus',
          getName: function() {
             return this.name;
          }
       }
    };
    
   alert( obj.value.getName() );
   var testing = obj.value.getName; 
   alert(testing());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this issue, you have to understand how Javascript sets the value of `this` in a function call.

There's a summary of all the methods here: [When you pass 'this' as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676)

For your particular case, when you do this:

```
var testing = obj.value.getName;
```

You now have a reference to the `getName` function.  You no longer have any connection at all to `obj.value`.  So, `test()` just calls `getName` as an ordinary function.  In Javascript when an ordinary function call is made, then the value of `this` will be either the global object (`window` in a browser) or in strict mode, it will be undefined.

In your case, `this` becomes the `window` object so `this.name` is `window.name` which points to the global variable `name` and thus you get the result 'Gerorge Thomas'.

In fact, if you run your code in `strict` mode, it will cause an error which is, in fact, one of the benefits of strict mode that it points out accidental errors like this.

---

On the other hand, if you execute a function with the form of `obj.method()`, then `this` is set to be `obj`.  So, when you do:

```
obj.value.getName()
```

that is equivalent to:

```
var o = obj.value;
o.getName()
```

which is the `obj.method()` form of calling a function which will set the `this` pointer to be the object, which in this case is `obj.value`.

---

It is possible to work around this issue in a couple of ways.  Here's an example of working around it using `.bind()`.

```js
var name = 'Gerorge Thomas';
var obj = {
  name: 'Cinderella',
  value: {
    name: 'HocusPocus',
    getName: function() {
      return this.name;
    }
  }
};

document.write( obj.value.getName() + "<br>");
var testing = obj.value.getName.bind(obj.value); 
document.write(testing());
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it only needs some reflection, let's analyse it:

- In the first alert we are calling the `getName()` method of the
  `obj.value` object so it returns `obj.value.name` which is
  `"HocusPocus"`.

> `alert( obj.value.getName() );` we call `this.name` where this refers to  `obj.value`  so name is `HocusPocus`

- But in the second alert we are creating a new function `testing()`
  with the body of the `getName()` method, so it will be attached to
  the global `window` object and if we call it we will get the global
  `name` value wich is `'Gerorge Thomas'`.

> `alert(testing());` we are dealing with `this.nam`e where `this` refers to the global scope so name is `'Cinderella'`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're calling a method from inside the `obj` object. The 2nd time, you're making a copy of the function (not really, it's just a reference) in the global scope. So you could also write `window.testing()` for the 2nd call. I think that makes it clear.

Comment: There's no copy of the function being made at all - there's still only one function.  There's an assignment of the function reference to a second variable.  But, that assignment has nothing to do with the OP's issue.  The issue is purely in how the function is called.

Comment: A minor, technical detail that doesn't really matter here, but I shall take your word for it.

Comment: @DanMan - it's the entire premise of your answer and it is not correct.  It doesn't actually matter whether `testing` is in the global scope of not.  Even if it's in a function scope, the same problem exists.  This doesn't have to do with the global scope.

Comment: It is all explained in my answer.  When you call `obj.method()`, the `this` pointer inside of the execution of `method()` is set to `obj`.  So, in  your second example, you've attached a new method to `obj2` named `getName` and you've called it with `obj2.getName()` so, of course, the `this` pointer in that method will point to `obj2`.  You may want to read [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) about how `this` is set in Javascript.

Comment: So it obviously is all about scope. Anyway, feel free to vote me down.

Comment: It's not about scope at all.  It's about how `this` is set based on how a function is called.