# global scope variable and their assignment

Tags: javascript, this, global

when foo() gets called, "this" inside foo function is referring to Global scope and "bar" variable has already being defined and get assigned a value of "bar".

so why inside foo(), "this.bar" gives undefined value but bar does not.

```js
function foo(){
  this.baz = "baz";
  console.log(this.bar + " " + baz);  //undefine  baz
   console.log( bar + " " + baz);  //bar   baz
 }
var bar="bar";
foo();
```

Comment: It gives me the correct result, bar baz, bar baz

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy strangely it's not working in jsfiddle but working fine in jsbin https://jsfiddle.net/pqdnv8ob/

Comment: do not use global scope variables

Answer (score 1):

> so why inside foo(), "this.bar" gives undefined value but bar does
>   not.

Probably your `var bar="bar";` is not actually in the global scope.  If it was your code would work as shown.  Referencing `bar` will find a variable in any parent scope.  But, `this.bar` when `this` is set to the global object requires a `bar` that is defined in the global scope.  So, we conclude that `var bar="bar";` is not actually in the global scope.

---

When you make a normal function call and you are not running in `strict` mode, `this` will be set to the global object which is `window` in a browser.  In general, this is NOT a recommend use of `this` and, in fact, it will break in `strict` mode.  But, I will explain what's going on in your code.

In your specific example, you can replace `this` with `window` and your code is essentially doing this:

```js
function foo(){
    window.baz = "baz";
    log(window.bar + " " + baz);
    log(bar + " " + baz);  //bar   baz
} 

window.bar="bar";
foo();


// display output
function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

And, here's the version when using `this`:

```js
function foo(){
    this.baz = "baz";
    log(this.bar + " " + baz);
    log(bar + " " + baz);  //bar   baz
} 

bar="bar";
foo();


// display output
function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

And, as you can see, there is no `undefined` value when you run either snippet.

---

If you run your code in `strict` mode (which is highly recommended), then `this` will be set to `undefined` in a normal function call and your code will fail.  Instead, only use `this` when you know it has specifically been set to a value you want such as in a constructor function called with `new` or in a method call or in a callback that is specifically setting `this` to a known value (probably with `.call()` or `.apply()`).

Comment: why my original code doesn't work before replacing "this" with window?

Comment: @Rita - See the part of my answer I added to the beginning.  Because your `var bar="bar";` is not actually in the global scope.  Is this is in a jsFiddle by any chance?

Comment: sorry I take this back.

Comment: Yes I was running it in jsFiddle. Now that I ran it on CodePen or Plunker., they both give me the "bar baz" value no matter if I use this keyword or window keyword.

Comment: @Rita - The default in jsFiddle puts your code inside an `onload` event handler.  If you click on the "Javascript" button and change the "load type" to "No wrap - in <body>", then your code will be in the global scope as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/qbtnx8a7/

Answer (score 0):

In javascript when a function is defined in the global scope, like you have in your example, the value of `this` is the global object. In your case because `bar` is defined globally it is accessible through `this.bar` within the `foo()` function.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the function is defined in the global scope or not.  Any plain function call will set `this` to the global object when not in `strict` mode or will set `this` to `undefined` in `strict` mode.

Comment: @jfriend00  Then why doesn't `var obj = { me: function () { console.log(this); } };` log `window`?

Comment: Because that's a method call and `obj.method()` sets `this` to `obj`.  See this other answer for more info: [The 5 ways that `this` is set in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676).  `obj.method()` is not a plain function call.