# How can I pass an argument to a callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I am writing a ping application that logs every ping to a log file. Depending on the result I write an info or a error entry.

Here is the ping function:

```
function pingServer(item){
    var monitor = new Monitor({
        website: item.url,
        interval: interval
    });
    monitor.on('up', writeInfo);
    monitor.on('down', writeError);
}
```

I would like to have a unique callback function writeLog instead of writeInfo and writeError functions, but I dont know how to pass an argument in that callback.

So instead of

```
function writeInfo(res){
    logger.info(getVarLine(res));
}


function writeError(res){
    logger.error(getVarLine(res));
}
```

I would have something like:

```
function writeLog(res, level){
    if (level=='info'){
        logger.info(getVarLine(res));
    } else {
        logger.error(getVarLine(res));
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to do looks fine. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I don't know how to pass level as a param in the callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three options:

1. Use `.bind()` to automatically prepend arguments to the callback (technically this creates a new function stub that adds that argument).
2. Manually create your own wrapper function that adds the argument.
3. Create a new version of `.on()` that accepts your `level` argument and adds it to the callback before calling the callback.

### Using `.bind()`

If you are not relying on a value of `this` being passed into your callback, then you can use `.bind()` to create a new function that will have the `level` argument automatically prepended to the callback arguments.

```
// note how the arguments had to be switched here so level was first to match
// up with how .bind() works
function writeLog(level, res){
    if (level=='info'){
        logger.info(getVarLine(res));
    } else {
        logger.error(getVarLine(res));
    }
}

function pingServer(item){
    var monitor = new Monitor({
        website: item.url,
        interval: interval
    });
    monitor.on('up', writeLog.bind(null, level));
    monitor.on('down', writeLog.bind(null, level));
}
```

### Manually Creating Your Own Wrapper Function

Or, you can create your own wrapper function that returns a function, but captures the parameter you wanted:

```
function writeLogCallback(level) {
    return function(res) {
        if (level=='info'){
            logger.info(getVarLine(res));
        } else {
            logger.error(getVarLine(res));
        }
    }
}

function pingServer(item){
    var monitor = new Monitor({
        website: item.url,
        interval: interval
    });
    monitor.on('up', writeLogCallback(level));
    monitor.on('down', writeLogCallback(level));
}
```

### Creating a Replacement for `.on()`

Or, you can create a wrapper for `monitor.on()` that captures your level value:

```
Monitor.prototype.onWithLevel = function(event, level, callback) {
    this.on(event, function(res) {
        return callback(res, level);
    });
}

function writeLog(res, level){
    if (level=='info'){
        logger.info(getVarLine(res));
    } else {
        logger.error(getVarLine(res));
    }
}

function pingServer(item){
    var monitor = new Monitor({
        website: item.url,
        interval: interval
    });
    monitor.onWithLevel('up', level, writeLog);
    monitor.onWithLevel('down', level, writeLog);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Just one question, when you say "If you are not relying on a value of `this`" what do you mean?

Comment: @ERodriguez - `.bind()` requires you to pass it, in advance, the value of `this` that will be set for the callback function.  If you aren't using `this` in your handler, then that will not matter.  If you are, then you will have to either make sure you pass the right value for `this` or you will have to use one of the other techniques.  If you don't know what `this` is or how it's set, then see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could achieve what you want (ie pass an argument to a callback):

```
monitor.on('up', writeLog('info'));
monitor.on('down', writeLog('error'));

// You pass the log level
function writeLog(level) {
    // and you return a function that will be called
    // with your data when the event is triggered
    return function(res) {
        if (level=='info'){
            logger.info(getVarLine(res));
        } else {
            logger.error(getVarLine(res));
        }
    }
}
```