# "This" within es6 class method

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, this

For some reason I'm getting weird values for "this" in my es6 class...

```js
'use strict';
class Clicker {
  constructor(element) {
    this.count = 0;
    this.elem = element;
    this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.click);
    
    // logs Clicker { count:0, elem: button#thing} as expected
    console.log(this);
  }

  click() {
    // logs <button id="thing">...</button> as unexpected...
    console.log(this);
    this.count++;
  }
}


var thing = document.getElementById('thing');
var instance = new Clicker(thing);
```

```html
<button id="thing">Click me</button>
```

### Question:

Why is the "this" inside of of the Clickers' click method referring to the dom node rather than ... itself?

More importantly, how do I refer to Clickers' count property from within its' click method if I can't use "this" to do it?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Why is the "this" inside of of the Clickers' click method referring to
>   the dom node rather than ... itself?

Because the specification for `.addEventListener()` is to set the `this` pointer to the DOM element that caught the event.  That's how it is designed to work.

---

When passing a method as a callback where you want to override the value of `this`, you can use `.bind()` to force the desired value of `this` with it:

```
this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));
```

**Explanation:**

All function calls in Javascript set a new value of `this` according to how the function is called.  See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for further info on that basic set of rules.

On top of that, when you do this:

```
this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.click);
```

You are just getting the `this.click` method and passing that method alone to `addEventListener()`.  The value of `this` will be completely lost.  It's as if you are doing this:

```
var m = this.click;     // m here is just a reference to Clicker.prototype.click
this.elem.addEventListener('click', m);
```

On top of this, `.addEventListener()` is specifically built to set it's own value of `this` when it calls the callback (to point `this` at the element creating the event).

So, you can use `.bind()` as shown above to force the proper value of `this` to be in place when your method is called.

---

For reference, you may find [this description of the six ways that `this` is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for a function call in Javascript to be useful.

---

**Other Options**

I find `.bind()` to be the clearest way of defining this, but you could also use either a local anonymous function:

```
var self = this;
this.elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    self.click();
});
```

or in ES6, an arrow function:

```
this.elem.addEventListener('click', () => this.click());
```

The arrow function will preserve the value of `this` for you automatically to avoid needing the `self` reference used in the prior example.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. expect your solution to be accepted in ~12 minutes.

Comment: @AndrewLuhring - Note, I added more explanation.

Comment: On top of this answer you could also solve it by using `this.elem.addEventListener('click', () => this.click());` I believe

Comment: @sniels - I added your option and one other to my answer.  Good idea.

Comment: It seems like this `this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));` syntax don't let us to remove the listener, like it is another function. But i don't get it really. Somebody explain me why it is behaving like that?

Comment: @AleksejBrume - It is another function - `.bind()` creates a wrapper function.  If you want to use the same function to then call `.removeEventListener()`, then you need to do something like `var fn = `this.click.bind(this);` and then use `fn` for both `.addEventListener()` and `.removeEventListener()`.

Comment: Check out `core-decorators` on `npm`. `import { autobind } from 'core-decorators'`. Then in your class methods `@autobind click () { ... }`. Makes me very happy.