# Why my array is still empty even though I had assign value to this array in my controller? (I am using angularjs, not angular)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

This question took me one day to debug it, but still no luck.

Problem: `this.gridOptions.data = this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo ;`
**this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo ** is still a empty array. Before this line of code executes, I have call activate() function to assign array to **this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo **. Please see this line `this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo = templateReorderProperties;`

P.S. Although I cannot get the value of `allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo` in controller, but I can get the value of it in html.

```
namespace app.admin {
'use strict';

class FooController {
    static $inject: Array<string> = [];

    constructor() {
        this.activate();
    }

    activate() {
        this.getData();

        this.classificationFoo = this.data[0];

        this.getTemplateFromGivenRepo(this.classificationFoo.id, this.classificationFoo.displayName);

        this.populateData();
    }

    data: any;

    classificationFoo: any;

    allDataFromclassificationFoo: any = [];

    // demo grid
    gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        },
        data: []
    };

    populateData() {
            this.gridOptions.data = this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo ;
    }

    getData() {
        this.fooService.getUserData();
        this.data = this.fooService.userdata;
    }

    getTemplateFromGivenRepo(fooId: string, fooName: string) {
        switch (fooId) {
            case 'FOO':
                this.TemplateApi.templatesAvaiableForRepoIdGET(fooId).then(data => {
                    data.forEach(element => {
                       element.fooName = fooName;
                    });

                    let templateReorderProperties = data

                    this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo = templateReorderProperties;
                }, error => {

                });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

class Bar implements ng.IDirective {
    static $inject: Array<string> = [];

    constructor() {
    }

    bindToController: boolean = true;
    controller = FooController;
    controllerAs: string = 'vm';
    templateUrl: string = 'app/foo.html';

    static instance(): ng.IDirective {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

angular
    .module('app.admin')
    .directive('bar', Bar.instance);
```

}

Comment: I suspect that the `this` in the function where `this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo` is written is a different `this` than you expect it to be. (@see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489579/this-within-es6-class-method)

Comment: @birdspider Any solution for me? I have no idea how to fix it and I tried my best

Comment: To test the theory about 'this' try just above you switch (1st line of method) and write `let _this = this` and when you assign the array do `_this. allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo = templateReorderProperties`

Comment: Notice the underscore :) want you to save and use the this instance of the outer scope

Comment: @cYrixmorten I did what you said, but still cannot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`getTemplateFromGivenRepo` is async operation.**

Move `this.populateGridData();` call inside `getTemplateFromGivenRepo` after

`this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo = templateReorderProperties;`

```
getTemplateFromGivenRepo(repoId: string, repoName: string) {
            switch (repoId) {
                case 'CLASSIFICATION':
                    this.TemplateApi.templatesAvaiableForRepoIdGET(repoId).then(data => {

                        this.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo = templateReorderProperties;
                        this.populateGridData(); // call here
                    }, error => {

                    });
            }
        };
```

OR

You can return promise  from `getTemplateFromGivenRepo` and in `then` able `success` callback,call
`this.populateGridData();`

Comment: Wow. Your first solution works great. You save my day. Thanks a lot. Could you please give me some tutorial or article about your solution? (async operation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323  This will over all possible scenario

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into the link you sent to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `this` instance that different inside Promise resolve.

Try to write in beginning  something like:

```
var self = this;
```

and after that change all `this` to `self` key.

a.e.:

```
self.gridOptions.data = self.allTemplatesFromClassificationRepo;

// and so on ...
```

By this way you will guarantee that you use same scope instance

---

Hope it will work

Comment: Could you let me know where should I put 'let self = this;' in my code?

Comment: 1st row in constructor implementation `constructor(private repoEventService,
                    private TemplateApi,
                    private $filter) {  var self = this;       self.activate(); ...
        }`

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I received this error: 'TS2339, Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'Windows' '