# 'this' context in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a Controller with two functions, and one calls the other using `this`, But when a call it the `this` is undefined

I've tried to follow [these instructions](https://www.athiemann.net/2015/07/19/typescript-class-method-this.html) when I make an exemple it works, but when I implement it in my code the this stills `undefined`.

Controller:

```
import AutenticacaoDAO from '../daos/autenticacao.dao'
import MailController from './email.controller'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import TokenSecret from '../config/token-secret'
import crypto from 'crypto'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { Usuario } from '../models/usuario.model';

class AutenticacaoController {
    constructor() {

    }

    public async login(req: Request, res: Response) {
        let usuario;
        try {
            usuario = await AutenticacaoDAO.login(req.body.email)
            this.tratarResposta(await crypto.createHash("md5").update(req.body.senha).digest("hex"), usuario) //THIS IS UNDEFINED HERE                     
    } catch (error) {
        res.json(error)
    }
}

tratarResposta (senhaEnviada: string, usuario: any) {
  // HERE I TREAT IF THE RETURNED USER IS BLOQUED OR NAH, IF THE PASSWORD 
  //IS CORRECT AND SOME OTHER STUFF
}

}

export default new AutenticacaoController()
```

I'm able to do my stuff inside de try statement(it works, i've tried), but the login function will be too big...

route where I call the login method:

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import AutenticacaoController from '../controllers/autenticacao.controller'


const AutenticacaoRoutes = Router()

AutenticacaoRoutes.post('/autenticacao/signup', AutenticacaoController.signUp)
AutenticacaoRoutes.post('/autenticacao/login', AutenticacaoController.login)
AutenticacaoRoutes.put('/autenticacao/esquecisenha/', AutenticacaoController.forgotPassword)
AutenticacaoRoutes.get('/autenticacao/recoverypassword/', AutenticacaoController.recoveryPassword)


export default AutenticacaoRoutes
```

Comment: where are you passing `login`?

Comment: You need to capture `this`, that can be done using an arrow function assignment. `login = async (req: Request, res: Response) => { /* your method body here*/}`

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489579/this-within-es6-class-method

Comment: @DanielA.White, I'm calling it from my route.

Comment: @Igor, I was trying to make this  way on `tratarResposta` function. I will try it on login.

Comment: The problem is not in your controller, but where `login` is used. Share the controller line. You probably just need to call the `bind()` function or use an arrow function when defining the route.

Comment: @Evert, I edited the question with the route that I call the login method

Comment: @TiagoSilveira you're running into a really common issue people run into with javascript, passing a function by reference loses its reference to this. Look up `this binding` on SO and you'll likely get to the answer. The answer will probably involve using the `bind()` function.

Comment: [Don't default-export a `new` `class` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

When passing down a function as a parameter (here would be your are passing `.login` function as a middleware for your route) your `this` that you use inside that function doesn't represent your controller anymore. You need to specify what the `this` value is when that function will be called. To do that, you use the `Function.prototype.bind(value)` method.

So that means you need to change

```js
AutenticacaoRoutes.post('/autenticacao/login', AutenticacaoController.login)
```

to

```js
AutenticacaoRoutes.post('/autenticacao/login', AutenticacaoController.login.bind(AutenticacaoController))
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) a great reference to learn about the `bind` method.

Comment: I resolved it changing the function to  `public login = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        let usuario;
        try {
            usuario = await AutenticacaoDAO.login(req.body.email)
            this.tratarResposta(await crypto.createHash("md5").update(req.body.senha).digest("hex"), usuario) //THIS IS UNDEFINED HERE                     
    } catch (error) {
        res.json(error)
    }` I will try to resolve it using your way, it looks better.