# access this in another es6 scope classes

Tags: javascript, foreach, event-handling, bind, es6-class

I'm using `forEach` inside es6 class and bind a function

---

**My question is:** how to access `this` in another scope of es6 functions ||

and difference between call function **without bind** or **with**  `this.logElement` or `this.logElement.bind(this)`

---

**What do I want to do:** get element clicked with `this` not whole `class`

```js
class Script {
    constructor(element) {
        super(element)
        this.ref = {
            el: []
        }
        this.ref.el.forEach((item, index) => {
            item.addEventListener('click', this.logElement.bind(this));
        })
    }

    logElement() {
        const that = this;
        console.log(that); // log element clicked not whole class
    }
}

export default Script
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489579/this-within-es6-class-method

Comment: that not forEach just a single element click ;'(

Comment: if you want `console.log(that); ` to be the clicked element you can remove the `.bind(this)`