# javascript - setinterval causing objects to forget properties?

Tags: javascript, properties, setinterval

This code works just fine:

```
function whatever() {
    var s = new a('ayy');
    s.recall();
}

function a(word) {
    this.word = word;
    this.recall = function () {
        alert(this.word);
    }
}
```

The browser would alert the user with `ayy`. But why, when done like this instead:

```
function whatever() {
    var s = new a('ayy');
    setInterval(s.recall,1000);
}

function a(word) {
    this.word = word;
    this.recall = function () {
        alert(this.word);
    }
}
```

But in this instance, the alert "undefined" appears every second instead of "ayy." Why is this??

Answer (score 4):

You are losing the proper value of `this` in your function because of the way `setInterval()` is calling it.

Change your code to:

```
setInterval(s.recall.bind(s),1000);
```

When you pass `s.recall` to `setInterval()`, that just passes a function reference and the value of `s` is not passed in when `recall` is called by `setInterval()`.  This is true of any function reference.

If you did:

```
var f = s.recall;
f();
```

You would see the same issue.  Using `.bind()` is a work-around to make sure that the function is called as `s.recall()` and thus preserves the value of `s` and thus the value of `this` inside of the `recall` method.

---

The value of `this` inside a function is determined by how it is called.  For a method to have the right value of `this`, it has to be called like `obj.method()` or something like `.bind()`, `.call()` or `.apply()` has to be used in order to control the value of `this`.  `setInterval()` is doing none of these.  It just makes a normal function call and thus `this` will be either set to the global or to `undefined` (depending upon whether you're in strict mode or not).

See [Controlling the Value of `this` in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for more info on how the value of `this` is controlled in in a Javascript function.