# Use of .call(this) on IIFE

Tags: javascript

I've seen an IIFE wrapped up with `.call(this)`, rather than just `()`. Why would this be done?

The context: https://github.com/dmauro/Keypress/blob/development/keypress.js

(As I understand it, `this` would refer to the `window` object - which is where the IIFE would be called anyway. It seems redundant.)

Comment: Oops, of course. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the IIFE is invoked without using `call`, the `this` inside it would refer to the global object `window` (or `undefined` in strict mode). Using `.call(this)` will pass to it whatever `this` is refereing to at the moment of the call (whatever the current context is). A situation where you want to use `.call(this)` instead of just calling it normally `()`, for example, is inside a class method where `this` will refer to the instance of the class and you want to pass that to your IIFE:

```js
function A() {
    (function() {
        this.name = "A";                          // "this" is not the instance of the class A
    })();
}

var a = new A;

console.log(a.name);
```

```js
function B() {
    (function() {
        this.name = "B";                          // "this" is the instance of the class B
    }).call(this);                                // because we explicitly passed it to the IIFE 
}

var b = new B;

console.log(b.name);
```

**Note:**

It's worth mentioning that with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you can have the benifit of using the `this` of the enclosing execution without having to use `.call(this)` because arrow functions don't have their own `this` (they don't bind `this`):

```js
function C() {
    (() => {
        this.name = "C";                          // "this"'s value here is whatever value it has outside the IIFE
    })();                                         // no need for .call(this) here
}

var c = new C;

console.log(c.name);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's just a way of passing the value of lexical `this` into the IIFE - nothing more so that `this` inside the IIFE will have the same lexical value it had in the surrounding code.  Depending upon where the IIFE is, `this` may not be the window object.  It may have an actual lexical and local value.

If you don't use `.call(this)` on the IIFE, then the `this` value will be reset in the function to either the global object (which is the `window` object in a browser) or in strict mode, `this` will become `undefined` in the IIFE.  Javascript resets the value of `this` according to how a function was called.  You can see all the six different ways that `this` is controlled in this answer:

[When you pass 'this' as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676).

To tell you more about your situation, we'd have to see the actual code in context.

In the particular code you added a link to, I don't see any particular reason for doing it as I don't see any references to `this` at the top level of the IIFE.  It appears to just be a coding habit that is generally used and is useful in some circumstances, but not needed or useful in others.

Comment: @GregoryTippett - I added some comments on the code you linked.