# Why does this event handler have access to the class properties when it is not in scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, scope

This snippet came from a medium article. Why does the first `<button onClick={this.handleClick1()}>click 1</button>` have access to the actual properties in the class?

```
/**
 * Can you explain the differences between all those ways
 * of passing function to a component?
 *
 * What happens when you click each of the buttons?
 */
/**
 * Can you explain the differences between all those ways
 * of passing function to a component?
 *
 * What happens when you click each of the buttons?
 */
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.name = 'MyComponent';

    this.handleClick2 = this.handleClick1.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick1() {
    alert(this.name);
  }

  handleClick3 = () => alert(this.name);
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick1()}>click 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick1}>click 2</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick2}>click 3</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick3}>click 4</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have typo(s) somewhere, `handleClick2` isn't being used, and `onClick={this.handleClick1()}` would execute the alert immediately on mount. It also looks like you're misunderstanding javascript scope based on your question, but it's unclear what your question is. There are no class properties in this component.

Comment: Class declarations are just syntactic sugar on top of the object prototype.

Comment: I removed listener for handleClick2 to focus on handleClick1 ... it shouldn't have an effect on handleClick1 ...

Comment: You don't actually use `handleClick2` anywhere in your code.  We could guess what you're trying to ask, but the question as written right now is kind of messed up and you're using some wrong terms to try to describe things.  Please fix your question.

Comment: I remove the other code to focus on handleClick1. The rest of the code isn't really necessary.

Comment: I put the full code back in

Comment: You would probably benefit from reading [The six ways the value of this is controlled in Javascript in function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676).  Several of them apply to your scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the first `<button onClick={this.handleClick1()}>click 1</button>` have access to the actual properties in the class?

`this.handleClick1()` invokes the function right then and there, i.e. **not** when the event is triggered later. `handleClick1` returns `undefined` so no event handler is actually bound.

And since the function is called as object property (`x.y()`), `onClick1`'s own `this` value is set to the value before the `.` (also `this`).

Comment: Excellent! This is the answer. Putting the execution inside a listener is just misdirection. Tricky ....

Answer (score 0):

Because it is binded with `this`

```
this.handleClick2 = this.handleClick1.bind(this);
```

[`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: But that binding is passed to handleClick2 isn't it? The very next click event, ```<button onClick={this.handleClick1}>click 2</button> ``` yields undefined

Comment: @bresson because you're assigning binded value to `this.handleClick2` not `handleClick1`, `this.handleClick1()` works because during initial render your `this` points to `MyComponent class`