# Why do I get logic is not defined in this code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to JS and React and the error I faced is

> "logic is not defined".

```
class Keyboard extends React.Component {
  logic() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{logic() ? "Yeah" : "Nooo"}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const box = document.querySelector(".mir");

ReactDOM.render(<Keyboard />, box);
```

Comment: You have to bind the functions.

Comment: It is `this.logic()` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get log is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536655/why-do-i-get-log-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use instance method using `this`,

```
<h1>{this.logic() ? "Yeah" : "Nooo"}</h1>
```

If you are calling another instance method in `logic` function, or you need to set state in `logic` function, in that case only you need to bind `this` to function in constructor,

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.logic = this.logic.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: but what "this" refers to since I do not use like const board = new Keyboard(). I do not use NEW keyword why this refers to Keyboard object without using NEW keyword

Comment: This is the way in React to call instance methods.

Comment: what do you mean? you mean <Keyboard />??

Comment: Keyboard is your class and logic is your instance method. To use instance method in your class you need to use `this`.

Comment: @Mirzhal, To know moe about this refer this - https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480

Answer (score 0):

You should put the "this" keyword before any methods that is declared inside the class component

```
 <h1>{this.logic() ? "Yeah" : "Nooo"}</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Bind functions in the constrcutor and access it using `this`.

```
class Keyboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.logic = this.logic.bind(this);
  }
  logic() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.logic() ? "Yeah" : "Nooo"}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const box = document.querySelector(".mir");

ReactDOM.render(<Keyboard />, box);
```