# Calling object functions in middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have this code in my middleware:

```
const UserMiddleware = {

  isNumber(n) { return !Number.isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && !Number.isNaN(n - 0); },

  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  validateSignUp(req, res, next) {
    const allSignUpErrors = [];
    console.log(this.isNumber(5));
    if (this.isNumber(req.body.first_name)) {
      allSignUpErrors.push('First name must be a text value');
    }
    if (allSignUpErrors.length !== 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 400,
        error: allSignUpErrors,
      });
    }
    next();
  },
```

I normally use 'this.' to call functions and variables in objects without problems. I suspect that the 'next()' function in the middleware is what is causing me to get the error below at the point of using 'this.' to call a function.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isNumber' of undefined

I have tried using 'bind' to call the function but the 'undefined' error still occurs.

Is the 'next()' function the one breaking the normal functionality? Is there a way to correctly use 'this.' to call functions in middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
this.isNumber(...)
```

to:

```
UserMiddleware.isNumber(...)
```

The value of `this` inside a middleware function will not be your `UserMiddleware` object unless you specifically used `.bind()` or some similar technology when passing it as middleware.

---

For help with further options, show us the code where you're using `validateSignUp()`.

For example, if you were doing:

```
app.use(UserMiddleware.validateSignUp);
```

Then, you could set the desired value for `this` by using `.bind()` like this:

```
app.use(UserMiddleware.validateSignUp.bind(userMiddleware));
```

Passing `UserMiddleware.validateSignUp` to a function immediately loses the association with the `UserMiddleware` object and the `this` value when that function gets called will be determined by how the caller calls the function and won't be the `UserMiddleware` object.  Using `.bind(UserMiddleware)` forces the desired `this` value to be set.  `.bind()` actually creates a wrapper function who's sole job is to reattach the desired `this` value and that wrapper function is what is passed as the middleware handler.  The middleware infrastructure calls the wrapper function with the wrong `this` value and then the wrapper function calls your `validateSignUp` function with  the desired value of `this` - probably using `.apply()`.

For a look at how `.bind()` works, you can see a polyfill for it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) on MDN.  For more of a discussion of how the value of `this` is set, see [Six ways of setting `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676).