# Value of This inside a function in es6 method

Tags: javascript, class, object, es6-class

So i was just testing how the value of `this` is affected inside an ES6 class method.

Can someone explain me why the value of `this` inside the inner function `undefined` in below code?

```js
class testingThis {
  outerFunc() {
    console.log("the value of this in outerFunc: ", this);
    function innerFunc() {
      console.log("value of this in innerFunc: ", this);
    }
    innerFunc();
  }
};

var newTest = new testingThis();
newTest.outerFunc();
```

Why is the value `this` not preserved in ES6 (not necessarily ES6 i guess) methods but is preserved in usual functions (like below):

```js
function a() {
  console.log("this outer: ", this)

  function b() {
    console.log("this inner: ", this)
  }
  b();
};
a();
```

Both inner and outer `this` in above code have the same value (`window`).

Comment: Just a heads up!!,.  Even in the world of ES6,.  Using the good old `var that = this` works for this type of sub function invocation.

Comment: I think what you really want to ask is: "Why isn't `this` inside the `innerFunc` the same as `this` in `outerFunc`?".

Comment: @MinusFour yes exactly

Comment: @Keith "in the world of ES6", using arrow functions where appropriate is even better.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts  The answer to that one,  depends.. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1541563)

Comment: Also [How does “this” keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/133973/1541563)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks i'll check those out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 class are automatically in strict mode.

That means that any plain function call sets the value of `this` to `undefined` within that function.  That's all you're seeing.

FYI, this a strict mode feature, and the only involvement of ES6 is that it automatically puts class definitions into strict mode.

---

In strict mode, any plain function call sets `this` inside that function to `undefined`.

When not in strict mode, any plain function call sets `this` to the global object which, in a browser, is the `window` object.

---

The new part of your question is two plain function calls, not in strict mode, that both set `this` to the global object. It's not "preserving" the value of `this`. It's setting it to the global object in both function calls.

Comment: ah okay .. if I remove the "strict" mode would it show the same `this`?

Comment: @VSX - You can't remove strict mode in ES6 class definitions.  Even if you did remove strict mode, `this` would just be set to the `global` object.  It's a fact in Javascript that `this` is changed when you call a function.  If you want `this` to be the object, then make `innerFunc` be a method or call it with `.call(this)`.  FYI, `this` is never preserved when you call another function.  It's always set to some value based on how the function is called.

Comment: @VSX And even if you could, the answer is no.  It would be `window`

Comment: @jfriend00 kindly checkout the updated post ... my main doubt is why working of `this` in a function nested inside ES6 class method different from the usual nested functions.

Comment: @VSX because you're comparing apples and oranges. In your second example, the outer function is also not a method, so `this` is `window` for both, as jfriend00 has already stated. It has nothing to do with "preservation", it's just that `a()` and `b()` are called without a context object.

Comment: @VSX - As I say in my answer a plain function call, when not in strict mode, sets `this` to the global object (which is a browser is `window`) and separately, when in strict mode, sets it to `undefined`.  So, all the new part of your question is seeing is two plain function calls, not in strict mode, that both set `this` to the global object.  It's not "preserving" the value of `this`.  It's setting it to the global object in both function calls.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks that explains it. So if the 2 nested functions (the 2nd part of question) were somehow in `strict` mode, the inner `this` would be `undefined` and outer `this` would equal `window` object?

Comment: @VSX - If they were both defined in `strict` mode and they were both called as normal functions, then `this` in both of them would be `undefined`.  The main takeway here should be that you don't use `this` in a function unless the function is called in a way that makes that value of `this` be meaningful and known.  See [Ways the value of `this` is controlled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for more info.