# ES6 Arrow functions vs ES5: how to know which function to bind `this` to when using ES5 non-arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, arrow-functions

I'm reading [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/) on using ES6 arrow functions. It gives the following example, where you have to use `bind(this)`, followed by the corresponding code with arrow functions.

```
var obj = {
  id: 42,
  counter: function counter() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.id);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }
};
```

It says `In the ES5 example, .bind(this) is required to help pass the this context into the function`.

**What I Want To Know:** Why do you use `bind(this)` with the callback to `setTimeout` rather than with the `counter` function? ie why isn't the above code like this:

```
var obj = {
  id: 42,
  counter: function counter() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.id);
    }, 1000);
  }.bind(this);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do you use `bind(this)` with the callback to `setTimeout` rather than with the counter function?

Because the `counter` function (which works like a method of the `obj` object) already has the proper `this` because you call it like `obj.counter()` so it gets `this` from calling it as `obj.counter()`.  Assuming you call counter as `obj.counter()`, then if you do `console.log(this.id)` on the first line of the `counter()` function, it will properly show the `id` value.

The callback you pass to `setTimeout()` however has no natural `this` value unless you use an arrow function or `.bind()` on the callback function itself because when `setTimeout()` calls your callback it does not set a specific `this` value (it just calls your callback as a normal function), therefore the `this` value goes to the default.  That means `this` will be `undefined` if running strict mode or the global object if running in loosey-goosey mode inside of the `setTimeout()` callback.

See the 6 ways that the value of `this` is set [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) when calling a function.

---

I should also mention that if you did what you were proposing like this:

```
var obj = {
  id: 42,
  counter: function counter() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.id);
    }, 1000);
  }.bind(this);
};
```

Not only would it not help the `setTimeout()` callback at all, but it would also bind the wrong value of `this` to the `counter()` method.  You would get whatever `this` was before the `var obj` definition (also known as the lexical value of `this`).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that functions defined like this within objects are often referred to as _methods_. Kinda helps contextualise their usage / scope a bit better IMO

Comment: Got it, thanks! And thanks @Phil as well for your note.

Comment: Actually wait, I still don't understand why using `bind` on the callback sets the value of `this` to `obj`, whereas using it on `counter` sets it to the lexical value. Why doesn't applying it to `counter` bind `counter` to `obj`?

Comment: @gkeenley - Because calling `obj.counter()` already sets `this` inside of `counter` to `obj`.  So, when you then use `function() {}.bind(this)` with `setTimeout()`, it is picking up that value of `this` (the desired one).  Doing `.bind(this)` to counter itself, takes the `this` value that was in play at that time and sets that for the `counter()` scope.  That has two problems.  First, it's the wrong value of `this` (it is not `obj`) and second, it controls the counter scope, not the callback for `setTimeout()` scope which is where your issue is.

Comment: Ok, all is understood. I appreciate it.