# why this inside function refers to global object in node when function itself is not defined on global?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

NodeJs:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this === global); // true
  }
foo();
console.log(global.foo); //undefined
```

*this* inside a function refers to the object on which function was invoked. So from above code I expect foo to exist on global object but that is not the case. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: That's the way JavaScript works. The value of `this` is a reference to `global` because the function is called without any other source for `this`. If you were in "strict" mode, the value of `this` would be `undefined`.

Comment: Ok, so on which object foo is defined on then? As in browser it's attached to window object (yes except in case of let, const expression in which case I have the same question). In my mental model I always imagine a function to exist on some object (which is window/global in case of global scope declaration). Can you explain or point to some resource? Thank you

Comment: What I mean is if I declare same function in browser in global scope, it's attached to window object.

Comment: Well there is no `window` object in Node. Functions in JavaScript are not really "on" objects the way methods in languages like C++ or Java are. What matters is how a function is *called* in JavaScript.

Comment: if you want `this` not to be equal to `global` then you have to bind the function

Comment: You might want to have a look at [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/8289918)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In non-strict mode in Javascript (often called "loose" mode), when you call a function as a regular function such as `foo()`, the `this` value will be set to the global object.

In strict mode in Javascript, when you call a function as a regular function such as `foo()`, the `this` value will be set to `undefined`.

Based on the results in your question, you are apparently running in non-strict mode so the `this` value inside your function is set to the global object when called as `foo()`.  The function declaration itself in node.js is inside a module so that function has module scope, not global scope and thus the function itself is not a property of the global object.  The `this` value has only to do with the fact that it was called as `foo()` in non-strict mode.

Keep in mind that the `this` value in a function in Javascript is entirely determined by how the function was called (and in the case of arrow functions, how it was declared).  You can see the **six ways** that the value of `this` is controlled or determined inside a function call here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676).

---

Now, for your specific questions:

> this inside a function refers to the object on which function was invoked.

That would be true if the function was called as in `obj.foo()` and `foo` was defined as a property of object `obj`.  But, that does not apply when it is called as `foo()` and `foo` is declared as a stand-alone function (not a property on a specific object).

> So from above code I expect foo to exist on global object but that is not the case. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Whether `foo` exists on the global object or not is determined by how `foo` is defined, not how it is called.  It has to either be specifically assigned to the global object or declared in the global scope.  In your specific example in node.js, `foo` is declared within module scope (which is actually within a module function) so it is local to that module scope and is not global.

Comment: Thanks this clears lot of things. I got how this value is determined inside function, but then is it true that stand-alone function, such as foo here, is not defined as property of ANY object, they just .. exist ... in global scope (not even on window/global object in non-strict mode). I cannot find it even on module.exports

Comment: @mustafa1993 - The code in a commonJS module in node.js exists inside a [module function wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper), so your function `foo()` is just a local function in that module function scope.  It is NOT a property of any accessible object (technically, it's attached to some sort of internal scope object, but that object is not accessible to user Javascript).  So, just like when you define a variable in a function as in `let x = 2;`, `foo` just exists in the current scope.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why question get's marked as duplicate. Though similar posts explain 'this' fairly but not the answer I am looking for. Your answer clarified things.

Comment: @mustafa1993 - Well, the `this === global` is entirely explained in multiple duplicates which is probably what triggered those.  But, the `global.foo` aspect of the question is not explained in those same duplicates.