# Getting the value of a Class property, inside a function in a module without sending in parameters

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, import, module

I've imported a function from a module. In that function I need to get a property of the class without sending the class as a parameter to the function, because I cannot send the parameter every time I call the function.

What I've tried, but didn't worked

```
import {x} from './export.js';

class foo {
  constructor() {
    x();
  }
  str = 'A String';
}
```

export.js

```
export function() {
  console.log(this.str); // Or Maybe Something Else...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside function in `not-strict` mode is refer to the global object hence you cannot use `this` to access class properties.

you can get more information on `this` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077795/why-this-inside-function-refers-to-global-object-in-node-when-function-itself-is)