# Why does this refer to window or object based on where parenthesis are placed? And return undefined

Tags: javascript

I am working on flexible javascript widget.  In the course of some testing, I noticed that the context of `this` changes based on whether the parenthesis used to call a function are placed inside an object or in the global context of its call.  Why do the parenthesis matter?  And why would parenthesis inside the object refer to window and when placed in global context refer to the object.  It seems like it would be the other way around.

Also `undefined` is returned in both instances.  Is there a way to execute the function without returning anything?

I feel like I'm missing something important about `this` and don't want to miss out.

```
//this refers to window

var dataSource = {
    read: read()  
};

function read(){
  console.log(this);   
}

dataSource.read;

//this refers to dataSource object

var dataSource = {
    read: read  
};

function read(){
  console.log(this);   
}

dataSource.read();
```

Comment: `this` depends on **how you call the function**.

Comment: Because with read() you are calling a function and read is a variable.

Comment: @elclanrs: Unless, of course, you're dealing with your favorite type of function: a bound function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is doing two different things.

The first example is executing `read()` as the object definition is executed (`read()` is available because it's a function declaration and is hoisted, though this isn't related to the problem you're experiencing). It is called without any context so its `this` is `window` (as per the specification, where `window` is the browser's global object).

The second example has a reference to `read()`, which is then executed at the end of the block. Because it's executed as a property of `dataSource`, its `this` will become that. However, if you first assigned that reference to somewhere else and then invoked it via that reference, you'd again lose that `this` context.

For fine-grained control of `this`, take a look at `bind()`, `call()` and `apply()`.

> Also `undefined` is returned in both instances. Is there a way to execute the function without returning anything?

A function always has a return value (`undefined` if not explicitly set), but you're free to ignore it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with hoisting. You can merge both examples and the behavior will be the same. Look at the example in my answer.

Comment: @slebetman My two examples return two different results, that's why I got confused as to what the parenthesis are actually doing.

Comment: @slebetman Sure, the setting of `this` has nothing to do with hoisting, but if you make that knee-jerk reaction then you probably didn't read my answer carefully (where I was just tangentially mentioning why it didn't blow up). Of course, had it been a function expression, it'd be `undefined` at the attempt to invoke it.

Comment: @alex so far this seems to make some sense for me, but what exactly do you mean by "executing read() as the object definition is executed"?

Comment: @carter I mean your first example doesn't assign a reference to `read`, it *invokes* `read()` and then attempts to assign its return value to the `read` property on your object. I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @carter: may I edit your two examples into just one example to clarify the behavior for you?

Comment: @alex Yes, I have been curious about why undefined is getting returned in both cases.  I want someone to be able to call dataSource.read or dataSource.read() which will load the dataSource object with other properties and such.

Comment: @alex: Both the first and second examples are hoisted, therefore mentioning hoisting is likely to confuse people because it appears to hint that it has something to do with the difference.

Comment: @slebetman Possibly, but you've left a helpful comment here now to pick it out so that should cut down on any possible confusion.

Comment: Ah, but long list of comments become hidden after some time. So the answer may still be confusing a couple of months from now.

Comment: @slebetman Hopefully your answer will bubble up the top if you believe it's more useful. I'll leave a note in the answer regarding your concern.

Answer (score 2):

The scoping of `this` can be a tricky topic in javascript. That said, I can expand my answer on the general rules regarding the scope of `this` if need be.

But to answer your specific question, whenever you reference `this` inside an object literal, it by default, refers to the object literal itself.

**Edit: as long as the function was invoked as a property of the object literal.**

Where as, almost in any other situation I can call to mind,  `this` will refer to the window object unless specified when invoking said function using `apply()` or `call()`.

Comment: *But to answer your specific question, whenever you reference this inside an object literal, it by default, refers to the object literal itself.* only if the function was invoked as a property of that object. E.g. `var a = dataSource.read; a()`.

Comment: @alex That is true. I neglected to mention that condition. Editing

Comment: @alex This is the case however with the OP's code which may explain my forgetfullness a bit =P

Answer (score 0):

When `this` is used outside of objects it refers to the global object which in browser environment is `window`. Otherwise it refers to the last bareword before the last dot in the invocation.

For example:

```
function foo () {return this};
var bin = {bar:{foo:foo},foo:foo};

foo();         // returns window
bin.foo();     // returns bin
bin.bar.foo(); // returns bar
//   ^
//   |
//   '------ last bareword before the last dot in the invocation
```

Now, as to why the location of the parenthesis matter. I think you should be able to guess by now:

When we add a parenthesis to a word (variable/name/reference) what we're doing is make a function call:

```
foo(); // call foo
```

If we don't add the parenthesis, what we're doing is refer to the object:

```
foo; // this contains the function foo
```

Note that not adding the parens is not calling the function. Therefore it should be obvious that when you do:

```
var bar = { foofoo : foo() }
```

What you're doing is passing the result of the function `foo` to `bar.foofoo`. The function is invoked without any "dots" in its invocation path. Therefore it doesn't belong to any object and therefore the rule of `this == window` applies.

On the other hand if you do:

```
var bar = { foo : foo }
```

What you're doing is assign the function `foo` to `bar.foo`. When you later call it as:

```
bar.foo()
```

the invocation contains a "dot" therefore the rule about the last object before the last dot applies.

---

See my previous answer to a related question for a detailed explanation on how `this` works in javascript: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

Comment: Is it good to explain everything in terms of *dots*? What about `obj["prop"]()`?

Comment: Well, that's just an alternative syntax for the dot operator. And yes, the "dot" is not just pretty syntax  in javascript, it is a full-fledged operator that has a specific meaning. So yes, in my opinion it is a valid way to explain it. Especially as it uses simpler language that has less potential to confuse.