# Why value of 'this' changes from document to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

In following code I am not able to understand why the value of `this` changes to `window` from `document` in function `handler` when I call it from the `document` context.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var handler = function() {
    console.log(this);       // this = window
  }
  console.log(this);    // this = document
  handler();
})
```

As per my understanding the value of `this` is determined from its execution context. Now when I am `document.ready` function `this` points to `document` which is expected, but when I call method from that context, why is my context changing to `window` from `document`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628 for a complete (really, I update it often) description of how "this" works in javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a function, the value of `this` depends on how the function is called.

```
var handler = function () {
    console.log(this); // this = window
};
```

In this case, the value of `this` is not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object i.e window.

In the global execution context (outside of any function), `this` refers to the global object, whether in strict mode or not.

```
console.log(this); // this = document
```

Comment: That means `this` points to the object the function belongs to and here `handler` belongs to `window` hence it is `window`. So If use strict mode `this` will point to nothing i.e. `undefined`. right?

Comment: @Shree you are right. [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, whenever you see a bare function call, i.e. "handler()", JavaScript will call it as if you wrote:

```
handler.call(null);
```

This is different from, say, `foo.handler()` in which case it will run as:

```
handler.call(foo);
```

If you want to see `document` inside your function, you need this:

```
handler.call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The this keyword refers to the head object in nested functions [source](http://books.google.com.np/books?id=QedCPXDfzjAC&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5&dq=The+this+keyword+refers+to+the+head+object+in+nested+functions&source=bl&ots=i-UjxT98Yw&sig=zBJk6zpPwjrnb9FVwqq6451qksQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C7OjU67BDZaNuAT1nIC4DA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=The%20this%20keyword%20refers%20to%20the%20head%20object%20in%20nested%20functions&f=false): page no. 76 of the book

```
var myObject = {
 func1: function() {
   console.log(this); // logs myObject
   var func2 = function() {
     console.log(this) // logs window, and will do so from this point on
   var func3 = function() {
     console.log(this); // logs window, as it’s the head object
   }();
   }();
 }
}
myObject.func1();
```

So, in your case handler function is inside ready function in which this refers to global object i.e. window.

Answer (score 0):

Like this the context will remain:

```
this.handler = function() {
  console.log(this);       // this = document!!!
}
console.log(this);
this.handler();
```