# Why does reference to 'this' return the value, it should be undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have the module...

```
var myModule = (function(){

    var obj = new Object();
    obj.name = "";
    obj.sayName = function(){
        obj.name = "jon";
        console.log(obj.name); 
        console.log(this.name);  
    }
    return obj;

})()

myModule.sayName();
```

This prints the word 'jon' twice as per the console.log statements.

However I don't really understand why 'this' is correct since it would return the reference to the function and be 'undefined' wouldn't it?

Comment: `this` is `obj` because `obj` is `myModule` and  you call the function like `myModule.sayName()`, notice the dot.

Comment: But I thought because it is a new function that it will get is's own closure?

Comment: This has nothing to do with closures or scope but rather with how `this` works in javascript. Basically if called as `a.b.c()` the `this` in `c` refers to the last name before the last dot - `b`. So in your case the last name before the last dot is `myModule`. See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `myModule.sayName()` so `this` inside `sayName` is `myModule`.

The value of `myModule` is copy of the object reference from `obj` (since that is what is returned from the anonymous IIFE).

Therefore `obj.name` and `this.name` are the same value.

Comment: but I thought the function sayname has it's own closure all to it's self? I would have to assign this to 'self' in a higher function?

Comment: @Exitos: `sayName` is indeed a closure (over `obj` and a few other things), but that has nothing to do with what `this` is within it. `this` is primarily set by how a function is called, as Quentin said. When you call a function via an expression getting the function reference from an object property (`myModule.sayName();`), during the call to the function, `this` will be the object you got the property from (usually; there are *bound* functions that work differently, and ES6's arrow functions will work differently, but your `sayName` is normal).