# Return number's value from method on Number.prototype?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Before going in to the details of the issue I'm already fully aware of modifying built in's prototypes. This code is written in typescript.

Ok so I'm running in to an issue when I'm trying to return a number's value from a method on Number.prototype.

Here is the definition on Number.prototype:

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'tap', {
  value: function numberTap (fn: (t: number) => void): number {
    fn.call(null, this.valueOf());
    return this.valueOf();
  }
});
```

and the test I'm running:

```
describe('Number.prototype.tap((value:number) => void): number', () => {
  it('is defined', function () {
    expect(Number.prototype.tap).to.be.a('function');
  });

  it('returns the same value as its entry point in the method chain', () => {
    expect((1).tap(n => 5)).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

It doesn't equal `1` but `[Number 1]`. If I call `[Number 1].valueOf()` then it returns `1`. I'm already calling `this.valueOf()` when returning from tap. Anyone know what's going on here.

Comment: I just ran those tests with your prototype extension in the scope of the describe block, and both tests passed. Are you running your tests with ts-node, or are you compiling them?

Comment: I am compiling the code with tsc and mocha runs the js version.

Comment: Related: [Why does String.prototype log it's object like a standard object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26072173/1048572) - just use strict mode and you won't need `valueOf()` at all because `this` will be your primitive value

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the following:

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'tap', {
  value: function numberTap(fn) {
    fn.call(null, this.valueOf());
    return this.valueOf();
  }
});

typeof (1).tap(function(){})
```

and it runs just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing a require that defined Number.prototype.tap and had Object.prototype.tap already defined so it was causing this issue.