# What is 'this' refering to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, this

I know that 'this' refers to object of the function using 'this'. So in this case, which object 'this' in the function(req, res) is referring to?

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(dir);
  ...
}
```

Comment: `this` will always bind to whoever was calling the function

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking who is calling this function

Comment: what did u get on console?

Comment: @slier—the caller is not *this*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how `router.post()` calls the callback. The first place to look is the documentation. If it's not documented then look at the code. In general, one may assume that if there is no special handling of `this` then it points to the global object (or undefined if in strict mode).

If `router.post()` is implemented like this:

```
router.post = function (route, callback) {
    // ..
    callback(a,b,c);
}
```

then `this` will point to the global object or undefined depending on weather or not you `"use strict"`.

But `router.post()` can also be implemented like this:

```
router.post = function (route, callback) {
    // ..
    callback.call(something,a,b,c);
}
```

in which case `this` will point to whatever that `something` is.

Or it could also be implemented like this:

```
router.post = function (route, callback) {
    // ..
    var foo = {
       a : callback
    }
    a(a,b,c);
}
```

in which case `this` will point to the `foo` object.

As you can see, in javascript the caller determines the value of `this`.

See my answer to this related question to understand how `this` behaves in javascript: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

---

### Additional answer:

If you've read the link above then you'd also realize that you can force `this` to be whatever you want it to be using `bind` or a closure:

```
router.post('/upload', (function(req, res, next){
    console.log(this); // prints whatever myThis below points to
    console.log(dir);
}).bind(myThis));
```

Comment: +1 but not so much "the caller", but "how it's called", if that's not splitting hairs too much (since it might be called from global code). ;-)

Comment: Ah, my definition of "the caller" is a bit different from yours. I'm guessing you assume the caller to refer to the context from which a function is called. I used the term "the caller" to refer to the programmer behind the keyboard :)

Comment: Yes. Maybe I'm just causing confusion…

Comment: @RobG: No, clarification is good. If you misunderstood me then most likely I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

According to doc, this refer to the owner of the object.
In your case, the owner of the function should be defined in the router.post (if any)

```
//Definition of router.post
router.post = function(string, block) {    
    block(x,y,z);
}
```

and in this case, this should have no owner?
Usually when I use "this", I need to use the keyword "new"

```
function Foo()
{
    this.a = 1;
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.a);  // 1
```