# javascript class accessibility variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, class, object, scope

I'm writing a short class (first time using class in Javascript) for handling a menu icon for my site. this menu icon need to be able to be instancied multiple time on the same page.

I have an issue when using scroll event fired function that seems to not be affected to the right class instance, here is my pseudo code:

```
var DynMenu = function(Name) {
 this.Name = Name;

 this.scrollHandler = function() {
     alert("Scroll: "+this.Name);
 };

 DynMenu.prototype.Pause = function() {
     alert("Pausing menu: "+this.Name);
     $(window).off("scroll", this.scrollHandler);
 };

 DynMenu.prototype.Start = function() {
     alert("Starting menu: "+this.Name);
     $(window).scroll(this.scrollHandler);
 };
}
```

this code is invoked and used with the following:

```
var RevendMenu = new DynMenu("MenuIcon1");
RevendMenu.Start();
RevendMenu.Pause();
```

When Scrolling the page (after calling RevendMenu.Start() but before calling RevendMenu.Pause()), I get the message "Scroll: undefined"

May you tell me why I don't get the value of this.Name and how I can fix this?

Thanks a lot
Regards
Florent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers in the browser either set `this` to the element that triggered that event or, in cases where there is no element that triggers the event, the global object. In browsers the global object is `window`.

In order to bind this to the object the method belongs to you can use `.bind()`:

```
$(window).off("scroll", this.scrollHandler.bind(this));
```

Or, in older browsers that don't have `.bind()` you can capture `this` in a closure:

```
var that = this;
$(window).off("scroll", function() {that.scrollHandler()});
```

---

For a more detailed explanation of how `this` works, see this: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

Comment: Great thanks Slebetman a lot for your help and the link which is very interesting

Comment: I confirm this is working great to retrieve my object variable but the off doesn't work anymore and I didn't understand why so far, any idea ?

Comment: @ehretf: I don't use jQuery much so you have to read the documentation for the `.off()` method. As for the reason for why the `this` didn't work before, check out the link I referenced at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thnaks for your reply, I have checked your post and it is very instructive and well explained. I tried some changes but I didn't find a way to remove the scroll when invoking DynMenu.Pause() while using bind. Replacing `.off()` with `window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler.bind(this), false);` and `.on()` with `window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler.bind(this), false);` is the same

Comment: Ah. OK. I understand what `.off()` does now. To remove the event listener you must pass it the same function. All the solutions I showed you creates a new function. Therefore the function passed to `.off()` doesn't match any of the functions passed to `.on()`. To solve this, create just one function by doing `var myHandler = this.scrollHandler.bind(this)` then pass that variable to both `on` and `off` so that `off` may find the function passed to `on` in order to remove it from the event

Comment: Thnaks a lot slebetman, I came to the same conclusion and I confirm this is working perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help and all your feedbacks and explanations