# How does "this" work in functions that are assigned in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, this

I found this example code:

```
function personFullName() {
    return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
}

function Person(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.fullName = personFullName;
}

var dude = new Person("Michael", "Jackson");
alert(dude.fullName());
```

Which alerts "Michael Jackson". I changed it to call `personFullName` from the constructor instead of assigning the function object:

```
function personFullName() {
    return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
}

function Person(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.fullName = personFullName();
}

var dude = new Person("Michael", "Jackson");
alert(dude.fullName);
```

I would expect the "fullName" property to now be a string instead of a function. But now it alerts "undefined undefined". Can anyone explain why my version doesn't work?

Comment: See this answer for a full explanation of how `this` works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` is typically whatever comes before the `.` in the function call. So the fact that you said `dude.fullName()` is what caused `this` in `fullName()` to be set to `dude`<sup>1</sup>.

In the second version in your question, you're not calling it the same way. You're calling `personFullName()` without anything in front of it (which is correct, since it's no longer attached to a Person object). That means that `this` ends up defaulting to the same value as `window`. Since `window` has no `first` or `last` properties set on it, `this.first` and `this.last` are `undefined`.

To fix this, you can make your person be an argument to the personFullName() function:

```
function personFullName(person) {
    return person.first + ' ' + person.last;
}
```

and then call it like

```
…
this.fullName = personFullName(this);
```

---

<sup>1:</sup> Note that the method has to be a property on the object for the `this` binding to work. You can't just call `object.someMethod()` and get have `this` set to `object` in `someMethod`. In your code, the following would not work:

```
function Person(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.fullName = this.personFullName();
}
```

`Uncaught TypeError: this.personFullName is not a function`

Neither would this:

```
function personFullName() {
    return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
}

function Person(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

var dude = new Person("Michael", "Jackson");
alert(dude.personFullName());
```

`Uncaught TypeError: dude.personFullName is not a function`

You can get around this restriction in any situation with the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) helper method: `this.fullName = personFullName.apply(this)` does what you expect the second version of your code to do and you can also call `personFullName.apply(dude)` at any point and get `"Michael Jackson"` back.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the window in your `personFullName` function as it wasn't called in the correct context. You can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call it with the correct context without modifying the `personFullName` function.

```
function personFullName() {
    return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
}

function Person(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.fullName = personFullName.apply(this); // The magic
}

var dude = new Person("Michael", "Jackson");
alert(dude.fullName);
```

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative to fix that would be:

```
Person.prototype.personFullName = function() {
    return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The context in which your are accessing `this` in your second example, is referencing the `window` object.  `window` has no `fullName` property set to it.
If you add `alert(this);` to both functions you'd see what I mean.