# Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

In ES6, both of these are legal:

```
var chopper = {
    owner: 'Zed',
    getOwner: function() { return this.owner; }
};
```

and, as shorthand:

```
var chopper = {
    owner: 'Zed',
    getOwner() { return this.owner; }
}
```

Is it possible to use the new arrow functions as well? In trying something like

```
var chopper = {
    owner: 'John',
    getOwner: () => { return this.owner; }
};
```

or

```
var chopper = {
    owner: 'John',
    getOwner: () => (this.owner)
};
```

I get an error message suggesting that the method does not have access to `this`. Is this just a syntax issue, or can you not use fat-arrow methods inside of ES6 objects?

Comment: got it, is there any way to rewrite this function so that it refers to `owner` inside chopper?

Comment: While using the fat arrow syntax? Only if you alter the `this` value by first creating the `chopper` object, then doing the assignment in a function that has `this` pointing to that object. This can be accomplished pretty cleanly with a constructor function.

Comment: If you wanted to write that up with an example in answer form, I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: This demo will run in Firefox. Chrome doesn't have it yet. http://jsfiddle.net/bfyarxfe/

Comment: Ask the guy below to give you a demo so you can accept his answer.

Comment: ok, out of curiosity, why won't the following work?: http://jsfiddle.net/bfyarxfe/1/

Comment: @fox, you must use 'use strict' on that jsfiddle.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bfyarxfe/2/

Comment: chopper is `undefined`, since you also are in strict mode, variables must be declared before `var chopper = ...`. Again, sorry and excuse my english.

Comment: @fox: It works fine in a supported environment. Firefox doesn't yet have complete support. Try it in [Continuum](http://benvie.github.io/continuum/) and `console.log()` the result of the method call. It works.

Comment: @wZVanG: Strict mode would make it fail with an error because of the missing `var`. It would work without strict mode if Firefox had support.

Comment: See also [How does the “this” keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13441307/1048572) - the `this` in an arrow function always is the same `this` as if you replaced the arrow function with the keyword.

Comment: Mozilla docs says 
**Does not have its own bindings to this or super, and should not be used as methods**
[Mozilla Arrow function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Arrow functions are not designed to be used in every situation merely as a shorter version of old-fashioned functions. They are not intended to replace function syntax using the `function` keyword. The most common use case for arrow functions is as short "lambdas" which do not redefine `this`, often used when passing a function as a callback to some function.

Arrow functions cannot be used to write object methods because, as you have found, since arrow functions close over the `this` of the lexically enclosing context, the `this` within the arrow is the one that was current where you defined the object. Which is to say:

```
// Whatever `this` is here...
var chopper = {
    owner: 'Zed',
    getOwner: () => {
        return this.owner;    // ...is what `this` is here.
    }
};
```

In your case, wanting to write a method on an object, you should simply use traditional `function` syntax, or the method syntax introduced in ES6:

```
var chopper = {
    owner: 'Zed',
    getOwner: function() {
        return this.owner;
    }
};

// or

var chopper = {
    owner: 'Zed',
    getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }
};
```

(There are small differences between them, but they're only important if you use `super` in `getOwner`, which you aren't, or if you copy `getOwner` to another object.)

There was some debate on the es6 mailing list about a twist on arrow functions which have similar syntax but with their own `this`. However, this proposal was poorly received because that is mere syntax sugar, allowing people to save typing a few characters, and provides no new functionality over existing function syntax. See the topic [unbound arrow functions](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/unbound-arrow-functions).

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it seems to suggest that the mailing list deprioritizes syntactic sugar, even if it would lead to greater uniformity/readability of code. As it stands, it's much more challenging to use the fat-arrow functions in an OOP context under ES6 than, say, under coffeescript.

Comment: As I understand it, syntactic sugar **is** considered a valid reason for considering language extensions, but as you say with a lower priority--in other words, the bar is higher for such proposals.

Comment: A bit confused. From what I understand for the function keyword notation, this points to the context of execution, where it is called, not where it is defined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . In the example above, can you really relay on on `this.owner` the be equal to the value that is defined on the chopper object?

Answer (score 17):

In this line `getOwner: () => this.owner` should be:

```js
var chopper = {
    owner: 'John',
    getOwner: () => this.owner
}; //here `this` refers to `window` object.

console.log(chopper.getOwner());
```

You would have to declare `this` into a function:

```js
var chopper = {
    owner: 'John',
    getOwner() { return this.owner }
};

console.log(chopper.getOwner());
```

Or:

```js
var chopperFn = function(){

    this.setOwner = (name) => this.owner = name;
    Object.assign(this,{
        owner: 'Jhon',
        getOwner: () => this.owner,
    })

}

var chopper = new chopperFn();
console.log(chopper.getOwner());
chopper.setOwner('Spiderman');
console.log(chopper.getOwner());
```

Comment: I'm getting an error here: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined\n    at Object.chopper.getOwner`

Comment: I see, it is the correct use, however the method esta always returns window Object. You would have to declare `this` within a function.

Comment: `this` doesn't necessarily refer to `window`. It refers to whatever the current value of `this` is in the enclosing environment, which may or may not be `window`. Maybe that's what you meant. Just want to make sure he understands it isn't some default value.

Comment: @torazaburo That is fine for me, I tried it, `this` now refers to class

Comment: What you have written is equivalent to, but more verbose than, simply writing `var chopperFn = function() { this.owner = 'Jhon'; this.getOwner = () => this.owner; }`.

Comment: Yes. You can also do, but in this case we will assign the properties on an object  `{prop: ...}`, like OP example.

Answer (score 9):

If you have to use arrow function, you can change `this` to `chopper`,

```
var chopper = {
  owner: "John",
  getOwner: () => chopper.owner
};
```

Although this is not best practice, when you change the object name, you have to change this arrow function.

Answer (score 3):

A quick tip that I follow to use arrow functions.

- Use non-arrow functions for methods that will be using `object.method()` syntax. (Those are functions that will receive meaningful `this` value from their caller.)
- Use arrow function for almost everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Another tip, in strict mode, `this` still refers to Window instead of undefined.

```js
  (() => {
    "use strict";
    console.log(this); // window
  })();

  (function () {
    "use strict";
    console.log(this); // undefined
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

This inside arrow function doesn't reflect context of the object. Instead it gives the context where the object method is called.

Check this, This gives some insight about when to use arrow and when not.
https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: No, `this` inside an arrow function inside an object literal refers to the scope where the object literal is, not where it is called.