# Why "this" is undefined inside a fat arrow function definition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

First I tried this -

```
const profile = {
    name: 'Alex',
    getName: function(){
      return this.name;
    }
};
```

Which works fine. Now I tried the same thing with fat arrow. In that case "this" is coming undefined.

```
const profile = {
    name: 'Alex',
    getName: () => {
      return this.name;
    }
};
```

This gives me an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

What I learned was, fat arrow syntaxes are way better handling implicit "this". Please explain why is this happening.

Comment: Yes, this question does answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unlike regular functions, Arrow functions does not have a `this` of their own, only regular functions and global scope have `this` of their own.

Which would mean that whenever `this` would be referred in arrow function, it will start looking up the scope to find the value of `this`, or in this case,  during lookup it found, that the `object` is not having a `this` of its own, hence, it went up to global scope and bound the value of `this` with global scope, where it won't find anything. These two examples will solve your doubt.

```
var obj = {
    a : 'object???',
    foo : () => { console.log(this.a) }
};

var a = 'global!!!';

obj.foo();              // global!!!
```

Wrapping arrow within a function

```
var obj = {
    a : 'object???',
    foo : function() {
        return (() => {
            console.log(this.a)
        })();
    }
};

var a = 'global!!!';

obj.foo();
```

Here, I have tried to explain the behaviour of `this` for arrow in depth.

https://github.com/anirudh-modi/JS-essentials/blob/master/ES2015/Functions/Arrow%20functions.md#how-this-is-different-for-arrow-functions

Comment: `obj.foo();` will print `undefined`,not `global!!!`.

Comment: yes because "global!!!" is printed in the console statement

Comment: I would like to add that since `let` does not create a property on the global object, if `a` in the first example was declared like `let a = 'global!!!'`. Then the result will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Are you sure you run the code in the browser or in the command line with `Node.js`? . `Node.js` has no window object, maybe that's why the result was `undefined`. Or maybe `a` was declared with `let` which I explained why in the other comment.

Comment: It uses var which make it part of global. It should print global!!!