# How do I Access the Value of an Input Field inside an Arrow Function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, anonymous-function, arrow-functions

I was recently making a Javascript color converter (Up for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188915/html-javascript-hex-to-rgb-and-rgb-to-hex-color-converter)) in which I have two functions that are called when the input is changed (The `change` event). So to implement this, I had code of the sort:

```
hexInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (isValidColor(this.value)) {
        // Conversion code
    }  
});

rgbInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (isValidColor(this.value)) {
        // Conversion code
    } 
});
```

Now following the [airbnb style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrow-functions), I realized that maybe I could use arrow functions to rephrase these two bindings as they are using anonymous functions. So I changed my code to:

```
hexInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (isValidColor(this.value)) {
        // Conversion code
    }  
});

rgbInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (isValidColor(this.value)) {
        // Conversion code
    } 
});
```

However, now when I change the value of my inputs, nothing happens. So to try and find the cause of this issue, I decided to open the chrome JS debugger, and added a few breakpoints to these calls. When I stepped through the code, I found the root of the error: `this.value` was undefined! So I decided to google up the problem and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589227/why-this-is-undefined-inside-a-fat-arrow-function-definition), which has an answer that states that "[a]rrow function does not have a this or [*sic*] their own" (The linked duplicate of that question says that arrow functions are not just a shorter syntax for regular functions). So now I don't know what to replace `this.value` with.

This leads into my question: *How do I access the value of an input field inside an arrow Function without using `this.value`?* (Please bear in mind that I am *very* new to JS)

Here is a code snippet that illustrates the problem I have mentioned above:

```js
(function() {
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("change", () => {
            console.log(this.value);
        });
    }
}());
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Comment: There's no reason to use an arrow function in this case. I understand wanting to use the newest thing on the block, but when it actually causes more problems than it solves... don't.

Comment: **Arrow function is not the new function.** I would recommend you spend your time learning why each is useful, rather than blindly rewriting all of your functions.

Comment: I don't see why this question was downvoted. Even if I didn't know what the answer is saying, I gave my full attempt to find my answer by including my. 1. Research, 2. My attempt to solve the problem through debugging. As someone new to the language, I wouldn't really know what exactly to search for.

Comment: I don't think the question is useful. You're of course free to have your own opinion on that matter

Comment: @kevin B its useful to the OP?

Comment: For me the question follows the rules, so shouldn't be downvoted because of an own opinion.

Comment: @JonasW. LOL. by that definition it is impossible for a question to not be useful.

Comment: @kevin b no. Not quite. Homework questions usually dont help the OP. Or duplicate questions if there is already a brilliant answer out there. And opinion based ones overwhelm the OP with endless discussions :)

Comment: Coincidentally, there IS already a brilliant answer to this question out there. Probably a dozen.

Comment: @kevin b then search it and mark it. Downvotes just make everyone sad

Comment: @KevinB I think you're defending your opinion rather than being objective.

Comment: No, downvotes send a signal to SO such that it can properly sort questions by usefulness/quality. Blindly upvoting everything circumvents this system.

Comment: Clearly that AirBnB style guide is clueless (again). [You cannot, and you should not, use arrow functions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572).

Comment: @Ele and, yes, I am defending my opinion, as that's what was directly challenged. Votes are subjective. Opinion based. If they were objective, we wouldn't need them.

Comment: @KevinB before to share the duplicated you were toooo much subjective.  Have a good day!

Comment: @Bergi I get what you're saying. The Airbnb guide is being way too general with its statements (Or it is assuming too much about its users ;-)) So I guess I won't just follow it word for word from now on!

Comment: @KevinB While you are entitled to your opinion, here is my definition of a [useful question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): A question which shows research effort (I had that since I showed _exactly_ what I searched for and my attempts to solve the problem), a question which is clear (I don't think the title can be any clearer), and a question which has enough context to be answered (Which is essentially the whole body of my post). Now if you feel that any of those parts are not fulfilled, then you may go ahead and keep your downvote. Otherwise it really makes little sense.

Comment: It is a duplicate, there's nothing you could have done that would have made it useful.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah move on and let him think whatever he wants.  The question was duplicated (that's right) but a downvote shows how subjective was it granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the available event param `event.target.value`:

```js
(function() {
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
            console.log(e.target.value);
        });
    }
}());
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment what's wrong whit this answer :-)

Comment: Just upvoted to revoke the downvote...

Comment: Well, this definitely seems to work! Thanks! (For those curious, [here is the relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target))

Answer (score 1):

Well without context you need scope:

```
hexInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
   if (isValidColor(hexInput.value)) {
      rgbInput.value = convertHexToRGB(hexInput.value);
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgbInput.value;
   }  
});
```

But i would prefer good code over good looking code, so just ignore the styleguide here :)

---

Now the codereview part: You could extract the whole logic into a more generalized function, e.g.:

```
function fromToConverter(from, to, converter){ 
  from.addEventListener("change", function() {
     if (isValidColor(from.value)) {
        to.value = converter(from.value);
      }  
   });
}
```

So you can do:

```
fromToConverter(hexInput, rgbInput, convertHexToRGB);
fromToConverter(rgbInput, hexInput, convertRGBToHex);
```

Comment: I fail to see why this was downvoted. Thanks for the code review part!