# Returns undefined when finding an item in an array in VUE

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have the code below that finds the item details in array which works well.

```
var findGroupId = medias.find(medias => medias.group_name === this.groupName)
```

My medias is an array variable. Then the result of `console.log(findGroupId)` is below:

[image]

But when I do `console.log(findGroupId.group_id)` the result is `undefined`. But when I try changing the demo [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) under **Using ES2015 arrow function** and do demo on **JavaScript Demo: Array.find()**, it works well.
Am I missing something?

Sample array output (fetched from database):
[image]
PS: trying not to use for loop to save some memory and time.

Comment: Can you post a sample array?

Comment: @Eddie Please see update, tried just using fixed array values, and works. but when I used the database from database, it's not working anymore. Maybe I think it's because of my array result format?

Comment: maybe try to `"console.log(Object.keys(findGroupId))"` and check if the the key is `group_id` without any spaces.

Comment: @DF No displayed value.

Comment: But logging `findGroupId` still gives you the output of your first screenshot?

Comment: @DF Yes it shows the same output.

Comment: So basically it does not work in fat arrow function? @ramedju

Comment: Using `this` on arrow function may not be the same with `this` on *regular* function. You might want to check on that.

Comment: @Eddie What do you mean by that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589227/why-this-is-undefined-inside-a-fat-arrow-function-definition

Comment: You might wanna read this one. Im not sure if that is the same issue though

Comment: @Eddie Seems that they're a bit different, coz it seems they're not using an array, am I right?

Comment: @ramedju I added an answer. Im not exactly sure if this solve your problem. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the arrow function might be referring to the document and not the object. One option is to store the `this.groupName` on a local variable and use it on your condition.

```
var groupName = this.groupName;
var findGroupId = medias.find(media => media.group_name === groupName);
```

Comment: There you go. That's it. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help :)