# Why is the Value of is 'this' undefined - Webpack problem?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm not quite sure what is going on with my code.  I think that Webpack for some reason is setting the value of   `this` to `undefined` I have no idea why.

The webpack file builds properly - but if I console.log(this) in my app.js I get undefined - Is there something I am missing?

```
this
```

should refer to the window and then the Controller where I log it in setVars ?

Here is my webpack file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require('path'
const entry = [path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js/app.js'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/styles/scss/main.scss')];

    module.exports = {
      entry: entry,
      output: {
        filename: 'scripts/bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",

            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              "style-loader", "css-loader"
             ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              "css-loader", "sass-loader?"
            ]
          }]},
          plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
              filename: "styles/[name].css",
              chunkFilename: "[id].css"
            }),
            // new HtmlWebpackPlugin()

          ]
        }
```

And Babel RC

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

import axios from 'axios';

```
  const Controller = {

    init: async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/nav.json');
      const data = res.data.items;
      Controller.createNavigationMenu(data);
      Controller.getVars()
    },

    getVars: () => {
      const navigationContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__primary-menu');
      console.log(navigationContainer, this)
    },

    createNavigationMenu: (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }
  }

Controller.init()
console.log(this)
```

Comment: What should `this` be in your opinion?

Comment: It should be window , where I log it at the bottom - and then it shoudl refer to the controller when I log it in getVars @user3637541

Comment: You might get some insight by reading this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589227/why-this-is-undefined-inside-a-fat-arrow-function-definition

Comment: @marcuspetty the `console.log(this)` in the top scope won't be `window` because it's not in the global scope. You are dealing with modules here, and in CommonJs modules the `this` keyword is usually `undefined` in the *module scope*.

Answer (score -1):

In `getVars` `this` is `undefined` because the function you use is a lambda function (`() => {...}`) instead of (`function() { ... }`). If it was a real function the context would be the context of the function. It would never be the context of `Controller` as that is just an object and not a class. So you could create a real class for `Controller` in order to create a `this` context.

```
class Controller = {
  // ...
  getVars() {
    // ...

  }
}
```

On the lower part of the file:
I do not know exactly what webpack does, but you should *not* rely on it leaving `this` as `window`. In fact you should *always* use `window` explicitly. That also increases readability as it is clear what you are referring to and it makes sure that you do not misuse `this` in a context in which `this` is defined, but not as `window`.

Comment: Webpack is a module bundler, and is quite popular in modern front-end development toolkits. https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: I know what webpack is, I did not read the code of it's `require` implementation though...

Comment: No, changing the singleton object into a `class` for no good reason is not the solution here.

Comment: Well, "for no good reason"... It defines `this`, if I understood him correctly, that is what he wants. And concerning the usage as a singleton: There are other ways to make sure, we do not instantiate multiple objects of a class. To be fair, I did not realize, it is supposed to be a singleton. Still, why do you think it is not a good idea, here?