# Unable to change this.state property: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys I'm making a very simple react app, new programmer here, and I'm not able to change the value of 'this.state.isModalOpen' as even when I console log it, it comes as false even though I literally changed it to true in the pervious line. Please help I don't know what is wrong. Thank you

order.form.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './order-form.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

export default class OrderForm extends Component{

    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            nameId : '',
            phoneNu : '',
            emailId : '',
            pizzaSz : '',
            topping : '',
            delivTime : '',
            instru : '',
            isModalOpen : false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
        .post('http://httpbin.org/post', this.state)
        .then(response => {console.log("Response: " + response)})
        .catch(error => {console.log("Error: " + error)})
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value })
      }

     submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    openModal = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.isModalOpen] : e.true });
    console.log(this.state.isModalOpen)
}

    render() {
        const{ nameId, phoneNu, emailId, pizzaSz, topping, delivTime, instru, 
            isModalOpen } = this.state;
        return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div className="contact-details px-3">
                    Customer name: <input type="text" name="nameId"
                    value={nameId} onChange={this.changeHandler}/><br/>
                    Telephone: <input type="number" name="phoneNu"
                    value={phoneNu} onChange={this.changeHandler}/><br/>
                    E-mail address: <input type="email" name="emailId"
                    value={emailId} onChange={this.changeHandler}/><br/>
                </div>

                <div className="px-3 py-2 pizza-details">
                    <p className="label">Pizza Size<br/></p>
                    <input type="radio" id="sm" name="pizzaSz" value="sm" 
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="sm">Small</label><br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="md" name="pizzaSz" value="md" 
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="md">Medium</label><br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="lg" name="pizzaSz" value="lg" 
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="lg">Large</label><br/>
                </div>
                
                <div className="px-3 py-2 pizza-details">
                    <p className="label">Pizza Topping </p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="bacon" name="topping"
                    value="bacon" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="bacon"> Bacon</label><br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="excheese" name="topping"
                    value="excheese" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="excheese"> Extra Cheese</label><br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="onion" name="topping"
                    value="onion" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="onion"> Onion</label><br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="mushrm" name="topping"
                    value="mushrm" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="mushrm">Mushroom</label><br/>
                </div>
                
                <div className="px-3 delivery-details">
                    Preferred Delivery Time: <input type="datetime-local" 
                    name="delivTime" name="delivTime" value={delivTime} 
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    min="2021-07-21T00:00" max="2021-07-28T00:00"/><br/>
        
                    Delivery Intructions: <input type="text" name="instru" id="instru"
                    value={instru} onChange={this.changeHandler}/><br/>

                    <button className="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" 
                    onClick={this.openModal}
                    >Submit Order</button><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                
                    <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen}>
                        <h2>Hi</h2>
                        <p></p>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import OrderForm from './components/order-form';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <OrderForm/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Arrow functions and "regular" functions have different `this` behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589227/why-this-is-undefined-inside-a-fat-arrow-function-definition.  Consider changing to a `function changeHandler(e) {}` style.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `e` ([Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)):

```
this.setState({ isModalOpen : true });
```

Read more regarding [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) on official documentation. The pattern you were using is for [dynamic Object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable).

Also as you are using Fat Arrow Fuction you loose context. This is because arrow functions use lexical `this` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function) similar question). To solve this, as an option, just get rid of arrow function:

```
openModal(e) {
  this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
  console.log(this.state.isModalOpen)
}
```

and [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) context to your function inside `constructor` method:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   
   ...
   
   this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
}
```

There is official explanation on React Docs regarding this https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: I did try that but I got an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` does dynamic object properties also work on booleans, is that the issue?

Comment: Wow thank you it works and I learnt some new things, thank you!