# Why this javascript snippet is not working?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My following code is working, but when I use ES6 syntax it is not working anymore. Please explain what is happening?

This code is fully working.

```
   function Library(){ this.books = [];};
   Library.prototype.addBook = function(book){ 
     this.books.push(book);
   };

   Library.prototype.getBook = function(index){ 
     return this.books[index];
   };

   var m = new Library();
   m.addBook('The Demon Haunted World');       
   m.getBook(0);
   // output will be like 'The Demon Haunted World'
```

Then I changed the syntax to some extent of ES6.
The code then looked like this:

```
   function Library(){ this.books = [];};
   Library.prototype.addBook = (book) => { 
     this.books.push(book);
   };

   Library.prototype.getBook = (index) => { 
     return this.books[index];
   };

   var m = new Library();
   m.addBook('The Demon Haunted World');
```

Why is this not working? I'm getting the following error:

```
    VM505:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Comment: because the this dont represent your object

Answer (score 5):

the `this` belongs to window and not the `Library` constructor. It happens because the arrow function `binds` the context `lexically` with the window object or the environment which is `parent`.

```
   function Library(){ this.books = [];};
   Library.prototype.addBook = (book) => {
     console.log(this); //window
     this.books.push(book);
   };
```

Typically in JS, we have two context/scope [ Global, Function]. In your case the `arrow` function points to `window context` or the `nearest parent context.` which is window.

Comment: You correctly spotted the problem, but your descriptions are highly inaccurate. References to `arguments`, `super`, `this` and `new.target` in arrow functions always resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment. That's all. No context, no scope, no window. JS has more than two types of scopes btw: At least global, module, function, block and iteration scope.

Comment: ES6 has... ES5, its only function/global... may be using eval you can create dynamic context and also try/catch has its own scope...