# Arrow functions as a object method - this is undefined not Window

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, babeljs, arrow-functions

I have a problem to understand **this** in Arrow functions.

I read a lot of answers for example: [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)
and explantation in this description [Link github](https://github.com/anirudh-modi/JS-essentials/blob/master/ES2015/Functions/Arrow%20functions.md#how-this-is-different-for-arrow-functions) and everyone say that **this** should bind to Window , but when I check these examples I see undefined, If any of you, know why?

```
 var foo = {
     bar: () => console.log(this)  // lexical this is window or something else
 }
 foo.bar()
```

I am using babel to transpile the code:

```
var foo = {
        bar: function bar() {
            return console.log(undefined);
        }
}
```

babel versions are:

- "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
- "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
- "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
- "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",

but lexical this is not Window only undefined, Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you're using webpack with ES-style modules. Code inside modules does not have implicit access to the global scope. That is, `this` inside a module is not bound to anything. Webpack apparently replaces global `this` references with `undefined` so that any global context does not leak in even if it's defined by the environment.

If you try to execute `console.log("this: " + (() => this)())` in the browser console, you will see that `this` is, indeed, `window`.

Comment: You can pass `{modules: false}` as your options to `babel-preset-es2015` to stop module processing, if you want.

Comment: I wonder what that would result in. I mean babel can't really know if it will be executed in a browser or another environment, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, window is not part of the javascript standard. And since babel doesn't know the context in which your script is running it will just use `undefined`.

In nodejs for instance the global scope would be `global`.
While `window` is typically global scope when you are executing your code in a browser.

Comment: Not quite accurate. Babel is explicitly setting `this` to `undefined` because `this` is specified to be `undefined` in ES6 modules.

Comment: So babels default behavior is to assume that input files are modules?

Comment: Not default, but with `preset-es2015` - yes.