# Vue $route is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm learning Vue router. And I want to made programmatic navigation without using `<router-link>` in templates file.
My router and view:

```
 router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            {path : '/videos',  name: 'allVideos', component: Videos },
            {path : '/videos/:id/edit', name: 'editVideo', component: VideoEdit },
        ]
    });

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        router,
        created: function(){
            if(!localStorage.hasOwnProperty('auth_token')) {
                window.location.replace('/account/login');
            }

            router.push({ name: 'allVideos' })
        }
    })
```

So by default I push to 'allVideos' route and inside that component I have a button and method for redirecting to ''editVideo'
button:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" @click="editVideo(video)">Edit</button>
```

method:

```
editVideo(video) {router.push({ name: 'editVideo', params: { id: video.id } })},
```

It works fine. But when I try to get id inside a VideoEdit component using `$route.params.id` I got error **Uncaught ReferenceError: $route is not defined**

Maybe it's because I'm not using npm for now just a cdn version of Vue and Vuerouter. Any solutions? Thanks!

**Updated:** btw in Vue dev tool I see $route instance inside the component

**Updated:**

```
var VideoEdit = Vue.component('VideoEdit', {
          template: ` <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Edit {{vieo.name}}</h3>
                    </div>`,
                data() {
                    return {
                        error: '',
                        video: {},
                }
            },        
            created: function () {
                  console.log($route.params.id);
            },
  })
```

Comment: Could you also put that part of the component code where you are fetching the param.id?

Comment: code added. You can check. Thx!

Comment: can you try console.log(this.$route.params.id) instead

Comment: yeah it works, but I thought $route is global variable... Anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Thanks to [Sandeep Rajoria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1323813/sandeep-rajoria)

we found solution, need to use `this.$route` except `$route` inside a component

Comment: after adding `this` i am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined`

Comment: @GopalSharma  How did you resolve this undefined error?  I have the same problem.

Comment: @noypee don't use es6 style functions.

Comment: Just in case anyone arrives here, you can use es6 with a little workaround, just assign the value to a variable in the component or to the store on component creation or load, even better, store it using Vuex in that case, then you can use it as much as you need with es6 style.

Comment: @GopalSharma See my answer

Comment: for my part is was this.$router.push not this.$route

Answer (score 13):

For those who getting the error after adding `this`

`TypeError: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined`

We need to use a **regular function** instead of **ES6 arrow functions**

```
data: function() {
    return {
      usertype: this.$route.params.type
    };
  },
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue inside of `methods`. 
```
methods: {
        forward: ({path}) => $router.push(path)
}
```
needed to be 
```
    methods: {
        forward: function({ path }) {
            this.$router.push('register')
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {path : '/videos',  name: 'allVideos', component: Videos },
        {path : '/videos/:id/edit', name: 'editVideo', component: VideoEdit },
    ]
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router,
    created: function(){
        if(!localStorage.hasOwnProperty('auth_token')) {
            window.location.replace('/account/login');
        }

        this.$router.push({ name: 'allVideos' });
    }
})
```

Comment: Some narrative would be nice to explain what you did here.

Comment: The vuejs router Guide doesn't make it very clear that you need to use Vue.use(VueRouter) if using a module system. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vue v2 & vue-router v2 then in vue-cli generated boilerplate way to access router e.g. from component is to import router (exported in router/index.js)

```
<script>
  import Router from '../router';
```

then in your code you can use router functions like:

```
Router.push('/contacts'); // go to contacts page
```

Answer (score 1):

For those attempting to use es6 arrow functions, another alternative to @Kishan Vaghela is:

```
methods: {
        gotoRegister() {
            this.$router.push('register')
        }
    }
```

as explained in the first answer of [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Answer (score -1):

In my case these previous solutions don't work for me so 
i did the following

`<script>
import Router from '../router';`

then in your code you can use this one

`this.$router.push('/contacts');`