# I want to get id from url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Please help me with my homework.
I make a system with vueJS (vueCLI, vue-router).
I want to get the id from the url, but an error occurs in my writing. How can I solve it?

Error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $route is not defined
```

router.js

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/s/:id",
      name: "Result",
      component: Result
    },
```

Result.vue

```
<script>
export default {

  methods: {
    window: (onload = function() {
      const id = this.$route.params.id;
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: what does that error tell you?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Vue $route is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860578/vue-route-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you've to take a look on the lifecycle of vue. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)

When you want to do something onload, you should implement beforeCreate, created, beforeMount or mounted.

And this.$route is not reachable because this you're creating a function in a function and then the this is scoped to the inner function not the vue context anymore. To solve this you could use arrow functions (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)