# What's wrong with this ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to get some data from my database with ajax. I'm using Node JS and Express to handle routes.
This is the backend code:

```
router.get('/isAuth', ensureLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
Permit.find({}).populate('authBy').exec()
  .then(permits =>  res.jsonp(permits))
  .catch(err => res.send(err));
});
```

And this is the client side:
const allPermits = document.getElementById('allPermits'),
      table = document.querySelector('table tbody');

```
allPermits.addEventListener('click', getData);
function getData() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('get', '/permits/isAuth', true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      let permitData = this.responseText;
      let responseData = '';
      permitData.forEach((permit) => {
        responseData +=
          `<tr class="dataRow">
              <td>${permit.name}</td>
              <td>${permit.destination}</td>
              <td>${permit.fromD}</td>
              <td>${permit.toD}</td>
              <td>${permit.notes}</td>
              <td>
                <button class="deletePermit" data-id="${permit._id}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
              </td>
          </tr>`;
      })
      table.innerHTML = responseData;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

The issue is that this line doesn't work: `table.innerHTML = responseData;`.
I also tried to `console.log(responseData)` but other than the success message of the ajax request I don't see anything - https://image.prntscr.com/image/6Otihd6jSMWPRdoz4y6y9g.png;

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean here?

Comment: Where and what is `table` defined as?

Comment: Just nothing happens, I also tried to console log the responseData and I don't see anything in the console.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are using an arrow function for `onload`. `this.status` won't refer to what you want it to refer to. Use a function expression instead. See [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196) for why.

Comment: Yep, you’re using `this` inside an arrow funciton, but you should use a proper function expression.

Comment: *"I also tried to console log the responseData and I don't see anything in the console."* In other words, it's `table.innerHTML = responseData;` that "doesn't work", the whole block is simply not executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using an arrow function, `this` inside the `onload` method won't refer to the request object, so `this.status === 200` will never 
be true. Use a function expression instead.

For more information see

- [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)
- [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710/218196)
- [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22939130/218196)

Comment: well pointed out, indeed. I kept reading the code and missed `this` :)